# Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overridden?

Tags: c#, overriding, hashcode

Given the following class

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public string FooName { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Foo fooItem = obj as Foo;

        if (fooItem == null) 
        {
           return false;
        }

        return fooItem.FooId == this.FooId;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // Which is preferred?

        return base.GetHashCode();

        //return this.FooId.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I have overridden the `Equals` method because `Foo` represent a row for the `Foo`s table.  Which is the preferred method for overriding the `GetHashCode`?

Why is it important to override `GetHashCode`?

Comment: It s important to implement both equals and gethashcode, due to collisions, in particular while using dictionaries. if two object returns same hashcode, they are inserted in the dictionary with chaining. While accessing the item equals method is used.

Comment: Read this one https://www.loganfranken.com/blog/692/overriding-equals-in-c-part-2/

Comment: Using visual studio we can generate Equals() and GetHashCode() based on our class props. see this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-equals-gethashcode-methods?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1486, accepted):

Yes, it is important if your item will be used as a key in a dictionary, or `HashSet<T>`, etc - since this is used (in the absence of a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`) to group items into buckets. If the hash-code for two items does not match, they may *never* be considered equal ([Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.8) will simply never be called).

The [GetHashCode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.8) method should reflect the `Equals` logic; the rules are:

- if two things are equal (`Equals(...) == true`) then they *must* return the same value for `GetHashCode()`
- if the `GetHashCode()` is equal, it is *not* necessary for them to be the same; this is a collision, and `Equals` will be called to see if it is a real equality or not.

In this case, it looks like "`return FooId;`" is a suitable `GetHashCode()` implementation. If you are testing multiple properties, it is common to combine them using code like below, to reduce diagonal collisions (i.e. so that `new Foo(3,5)` has a different hash-code to `new Foo(5,3)`):

In modern frameworks, the `HashCode` type has methods to help you create a hashcode from multiple values; on older frameworks, you'd need to go without, so something like:

```
unchecked // only needed if you're compiling with arithmetic checks enabled
{ // (the default compiler behaviour is *disabled*, so most folks won't need this)
    int hash = 13;
    hash = (hash * 7) + field1.GetHashCode();
    hash = (hash * 7) + field2.GetHashCode();
    ...
    return hash;
}
```

Oh - for convenience, you might also consider providing `==` and `!=` operators when overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

---

A demonstration of what happens when you get this wrong is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638761/c-gethashcode-override-of-object-containing-generic-array/639098#639098).

Comment: Can I ask ahy are you multiplying with such factors?

Comment: Actually, I could probably lose one of them; the point is to try to minimise the number of collisions - so that an object {1,0,0} has a different hash to {0,1,0} and {0,0,1} (if you see what I mean),

Comment: I tweaked the numbers to make it clearer (and added a seed). Some code uses different numbers - for example the C# compiler (for anonymous types) uses a seed of 0x51ed270b and a factor of -1521134295.

Comment: @Leandro López: Usually the factors are chosen to be prime numbers because it makes the number of collisions smaller.

Comment: "Oh - for convenience, you might also consider providing == and != operators when overriding Equals and GethashCode.": Microsoft discourages implementing operator== for objects that are not immutable - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx - " It is not a good idea to override operator == in non-immutable types."

Comment: @antiduh by that token, it is also not a good idea to mess with GetHashCode for immutable types, which by implication means not to mess with Equals! So: if it isn't value-esque (regardless of `class` vs `class`), don't mess with equality - a reasonable rule of thumb.

Comment: So does it make sense to intentionally make GetHashCode less precise than equals, to speed up dictionary lookups? So far i've always mirrored the logic I use in .Equals and GetHashCode. EDIT: Answer to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305324/why-use-gethashcode-over-equals

Comment: Microsoft says - The default implementation of the GetHashCode method does not guarantee unique return values for different objects. Furthermore, the .NET Framework does not guarantee the default implementation of the GetHashCode method, and the value it returns will be the same between different versions of the .NET Framework. Consequently, the default implementation of this method must not be used as a unique object identifier for hashing purposes

Comment: @RGI more generally, `GetHashCode()` is never guaranteed between `AppDomain`, so that is not a significant statement; the rest is just a re-statement of the second bullet in the answer. The default implementation is find for *hashing*, but cannot be used as a *unique identifier* - everything we already said.

Comment: Don't forget to check whether field1, field2, etc... are null if they can possible be null.

Comment: Minor note - This particular implementation of computing the hash is vulnerable to generating an integer overflow exception if the /checked project compiler setting is enabled. Consider wrapping computations with unchecked{}

Comment: @Neil fair observation; Unchecked is the compiler default, but you are right: it shouldn't be assumed

Comment: Shouldn't we check whether `field1` and `field2` are null while calculating hash, if it is nullable?

Comment: @Lijo yes, you should

Comment: @Richard no, it should not

Comment: Can somebody comment on the following GetHashCode() rules outlined in Effective c# 4.0 by Bill Wagner? Rule 1) suggests that objA.Equals(objB) == true does not imply that both objects must return same hashcode. This is simply not true as some LINQ methods (ie. Distinct()) start to misbehave. I was very surprised to find such error in a handbook of such caliber: "If two objects are equal (as defined by operator==), they must generate the same hash value. Otherwise, hash codes can’t be used to find objects in containers.
"

Comment: @grzegorz_p that is backwards; two things having the same hash-code does **not** imply that they are equal (`Equals` == true), however, two things that report as equal (`Equals` == true) **must** return the same hashcode, otherwise they've broken the API. Are you sure you aren't simply misreading the paragraph? To quote from MSDN: "If your overridden Equals method returns true when two objects are tested for equality, your overridden GetHashCode method must return the same value for the two objects."

Comment: Fun fact: Microsoft [got it wrong too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54243461/stringcomparer-invariantcultureignorecase-equals-vs-gethashcode-disagree-for-equ#comment95314327_54243461).

Comment: After reading all of these different answers, I don't think there is a valid reason to actually override these methods. It could get very complicated with nested objects/cycles. Instead I have opted to implement an extension method to check equality in my way for my specific case.

Comment: In addition to providing an informative answer, the link in "A demonstration of what happens when you get this wrong is here." is *very* helpful and provides additional clarity.  Thank you!

Comment: May I ask why you're not using the built-in class `System.HashCode` for this calculation? I mean, something like: `var hc = new System.HashCode();- hc.Add(field1.GetHashCode()); hc.Add(field2.GetHashCode()); return hc.ToHashCode();`

Comment: @Matt sure! simple answer: `Dec 16 '08`

Comment: @MarcGravell - You mean, System.HashCode did not exist when you wrote this answer? I see, thanks for the hint. :-) Maybe you can mention it in your answer (a one-liner "Update: ..." would be great)

Comment: I know this is quite old, but i have a doubt. Why you multiply the hash by 7? I suppose 7 is a random number you have chosen, but then why multipling the hash by some random number? Thx in advance to you all! Nice answer!

Comment: thanks, this helped a lot with list's SequenceEqual, had to implement my own equality comparer

Answer (score 155):

It's actually very hard to implement `GetHashCode()` correctly because, in addition to the rules Marc already mentioned, the hash code should not change during the lifetime of an object. Therefore the fields which are used to calculate the hash code must be immutable.

I finally found a solution to this problem when I was working with NHibernate.
My approach is to calculate the hash code from the ID of the object. The ID can only be set though the constructor so if you want to change the ID, which is very unlikely, you have to create a new object which has a new ID and therefore a new hash code. This approach works best with GUIDs because you can provide a parameterless constructor which randomly generates an ID.

Comment: i dont think it s very hard to implement has code. given these rules and better explained in effective c# book, i think overrident GetHashCode is rather easy.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the hash code should not change during the lifetime of an object"? Is this NHibernate specific?

Comment: @vanja. I believe it has to do with: if you add the object to a dictionary and then change the object's id, when fetching later you will be using a different hash to retrieve it so you will never get it from the dictionary.

Comment: @DarthVader, it is not hard to override GetHashCode().  And, it's not hard to override Equals() using reference equivalence (or Albic's GUID proposition above).  It is hard to override Equals() using value equivalence while still abiding by the rule that two objects that are Equals()-equivalent must return the same hash code: only object state that is immutable should be used in your hash code algorithm.

Comment: Microsoft's documentation of the GetHashCode() function neither states nor implies that the object hash must remain consistent over it's lifetime. In fact, it specifically explains one permissible case in which it might *not*: "The GetHashCode method for an object must consistently return the same hash code as long as there is no modification to the object state that determines the return value of the object's Equals method."

Comment: @PeterAllenWebb: The design of .net incorporated many aspects from Java, including some mistakes.  Because Java collections were not designed to allow users to specify alternate comparison methods and hash functions, the only way for collections to regard two objects as matching each other was for them to report themselves as "equal", whether or not they were actually equivalent.  This led to different types defining "equals" to mean vastly different things, which makes it very difficult for objects which encapsulate or aggregate other objects of generic types to know whether they're "equal".

Comment: "the hash code should not change during the lifetime of an object" - that is not true.

Comment: A better way to say it is "the hash code (nor the evaulation of equals) should change during the period the object is used as a key for a collection" So if you add the object to a dictionary as a key you must ensure that GetHashCode and Equals will not change their output for a given input until you remove the object from the dictionary.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I think you forgot NOT in your comment, it should be: "the hash code (nor the evaulation of equals) should NOT change during the period the object is used as a key for a collection". Right?

Comment: Except this has a flaw: if ON UPDATE CASCADE is specified, I can change the primary key, which means the primary key is not immutable.

Comment: @StanProkop I think ScottChamberlain's comment was correct, however to avoid confusion, the sentence should read "the hash code (and the evaulation of equals), should NOT change during the period the object is used as a key for a collection"

Answer (score 73):

By overriding `Equals` you're basically stating that you know better how to compare two instances of a given type.

Below you can see an example of how ReSharper writes a `GetHashCode()` function for you. Note that this snippet is meant to be tweaked by the programmer:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        var result = 0;
        result = (result * 397) ^ m_someVar1;
        result = (result * 397) ^ m_someVar2;
        result = (result * 397) ^ m_someVar3;
        result = (result * 397) ^ m_someVar4;
        return result;
    }
}
```

As you can see it just tries to guess a good hash code based on all the fields in the class, but if you know your object's domain or value ranges you could still provide a better one.

Comment: Won't this always return zero? Probably should initialise result to 1! Also needs a few more semi-colons.

Comment: You are aware of what the XOR operator (^) does?

Comment: @SamMackrill I've added in the missing semi-colons.

Comment: @SamMackrill No, it won't always return 0. `0 ^ a = a`, so `0 ^ m_someVar1 = m_someVar1`. He might as well set the initial value of `result` to `m_someVar1`.

Answer (score 50):

As of `.NET 4.7` the preferred method of overriding `GetHashCode()` is shown below. If targeting older .NET versions, include the [System.ValueTuple nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/) package.

```cs
// C# 7.0+
public override int GetHashCode() => (FooId, FooName).GetHashCode();
```

In terms of performance, this method will outperform most *composite* hash code implementations. The [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netcore-3.1) is a `struct` so there won't be any garbage, and the underlying algorithm is as fast as it gets.

Comment: Alternatively, `HashCode.Combine(FooId, FooName)` can be used. `ValueTuple<...>.GetHashCode()` uses `HashCode.Combine` [under the hood](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ValueTuple.cs,4ad64bceec148f3c,references).

Answer (score 44):

How about:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", prop1, prop2, prop3).GetHashCode();
}
```

> Assuming performance is not an issue :)

Comment: erm - but you're returning a string for an int based method ;_0

Comment: No, he does call GetHashCode() from the String object, which returns an int.

Comment: I dont expect this to be as fast as I would like to be, not just for the boxing involved for value types, but also for the performance of `string.Format`. Another geeky one I have seen is `new { prop1, prop2, prop3 }.GetHashCode()`. Cant comment though which one would be slower between these two. Do not abuse tools.

Comment: This will return true for `{ prop1="_X", prop2="Y", prop3="Z" }` and `{ prop1="", prop2="X_Y", prop3="Z_" }`. You probably don't want that.

Comment: Yep, you can always replace the underscore symbol with something not so common (e.g. •, ▲, ►, ◄, ☺, ☻) and hope your users won't use these symbols... :)

Comment: @voetsjoeba You have a typo: `"_X_Y_Z" != "_X_Y_Z_"` (extra trailing underscore for second `prop3`), but point taken :)

Comment: @LudmilTinkov safer change would be to call `prop1/2/3.GetHashCode()`, and then underscores wouldn't make a difference

Answer (score 44):

Please don´t forget to check the obj parameter against `null` when overriding `Equals()`.
And also compare the type.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    Foo fooItem = obj as Foo;

    if (fooItem == null)
    {
       return false;
    }

    return fooItem.FooId == this.FooId;
}
```

The reason for this is: `Equals` must return false on comparison to `null`. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx

Comment: This check for type will fail in the situation where a subclass refers to the superclass Equals method as part of it's own comparison (i.e. base.Equals(obj))  - should use as instead

Comment: @sweetfa: It depends on how the Equals method of the subclass is implemented. It could also call base.Equals((BaseType)obj)) which would be working fine.

Comment: No it won't: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx. And besides, the implementation of a method should not fail or succeed depending on the way it is called. If the runtime-type of an object is a subclass of some baseclass then the Equals() of the baseclass should return true if `obj` indeed is equal to `this` no matter how Equals() of the baseclass was called.

Comment: Moving the `fooItem` to the top and then checking it for null will perform better in the case of null or a wrong type.

Comment: @IllidanS4 unless you're working with a value type. But then why would you be overriding a value type's Equals.

Comment: @40Alpha Well, yeah, then `obj as Foo` would be invalid.

Answer (score 20):

Just to add on above answers:

If you don't override Equals then the default behavior is that references of the objects are compared. The same applies to hashcode - the default implmentation is typically based on a memory address of the reference.
Because you did override Equals it means the correct behavior is to compare whatever you implemented on Equals and not the references, so you should do the same for the hashcode.

Clients of your class will expect the hashcode to have similar logic to the equals method, for example linq methods which use a IEqualityComparer first compare the hashcodes and only if they're equal they'll compare the Equals() method which might be more expensive to run, if we didn't implement hashcode, equal object will probably have different hashcodes (because they have different memory address) and will be determined wrongly as not equal (Equals() won't even hit).

In addition, except the problem that you might not be able to find your object if you used it in a dictionary (because it was inserted by one hashcode and when you look for it the default hashcode will probably be different and again the Equals() won't even be called, like Marc Gravell explains in his answer, you also introduce a violation of the dictionary or hashset concept which should not allow identical keys - 
you already declared that those objects are essentially the same when you overrode Equals so you don't want both of them as different keys on a data structure which suppose to have a unique key. But because they have a different hashcode the "same" key will be inserted as different one.

Answer (score 18):

It is because the framework requires that two objects that are the same must have the same hashcode.  If you override the equals method to do a special comparison of two objects and the two objects are considered the same by the method, then the hash code of the two objects must also be the same.  (Dictionaries and Hashtables rely on this principle).

Comment: OK, that makes sense now. So if the hashcodes of two distinct instances are different but they should be treated as logically equal, you can't use them reliably in a Dictionary or Hashtable. That's an abstract requirement, but now I get it.

Answer (score 15):

We have two problems to cope with.

1. You cannot provide a sensible `GetHashCode()` if any field in the
   object can be changed.   Also often a object will NEVER be used in a
   collection that depends on  `GetHashCode()`.   So the cost of
   implementing `GetHashCode()` is often not worth it, or it is not
   possible.
2. If someone puts your object in a collection that calls
   `GetHashCode()` and you have overrided `Equals()` without also making
   `GetHashCode()` behave in a correct way, that person may spend days
   tracking down the problem.

Therefore by default I do.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public string FooName { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Foo fooItem = obj as Foo;

        if (fooItem == null)
        {
           return false;
        }

        return fooItem.FooId == this.FooId;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // Some comment to explain if there is a real problem with providing GetHashCode() 
        // or if I just don't see a need for it for the given class
        throw new Exception("Sorry I don't know what GetHashCode should do for this class");
    }
}
```

Comment: Throwing an exception from GetHashCode is a violation of the Object contract.  There is no difficulty defining a `GetHashCode` function such that any two objects which are equal return the same hash code; `return 24601;` and `return 8675309;` would both be valid implementations of `GetHashCode`.  Performance of `Dictionary` will only be decent when the number of items is small, and will get very bad if the number of items gets large, but it will work correctly in any case.

Comment: @supercat,  It is not possible to implement GetHashCode in a sensible way if the identify fields in the object can change, as the hash code must never change.   Doing what you say could lead someone having to spend many days tracking down the performance problem, then many weeks on a large system redesigning to remove the use of the dictionaries.

Comment: I used to do something like this for all classes I defined that needed Equals(), and where I was completely sure I'd never use that object as a key in a collection. Then one day a program where I'd used an object like that as input to a DevExpress XtraGrid control crashed. It turns out XtraGrid, behind my back, was creating a HashTable or something based on my objects. I got into a minor argument with the DevExpress support people about this. I said it was not smart that they based their component's functionality and reliability on an unknown customer implementation of an obscure method.

Comment: The DevExpress people were rather snarky, basically saying I must be an idiot to throw an exception in a GetHashCode() method. I still think they should find an alternative method of doing what they're doiing - I recall Marc Gravell on a different thread describing how he builds a dictionary of arbitrary objects without being dependent on GetHashCode() - can't recall how he did it though.

Comment: @RenniePet, must better having a crush due to throwing an exception, then having a very hard to find bug due to an invalid implementation.

Comment: Yeah, that was my attitude too until the DevExpress XtraGrid problem. Now I just deliberately neglect to write GetHashCode() methods, and suppress the compile-time warnings from Code Analysis and ReSharper.

Comment: Lesson here: Don't use DevExpress, ever, for anything.

Comment: @IanRingrose: It is common for immutable classes to construct mutable class objects store information in them, and then refrain from ever modifying them or making references to those objects available to code that might modify them.  The fact that a class is mutable does not imply that all instances of that class will be subject to modification while stored as a key in a dictionary.

Comment: could you compute the value once the first time and then not change it later? there's no reason that the hashcode _must_ be dependent on the fields, that's just a nice way to evenly distribute hashcodes.

Comment: @DaveCousineau there is the requirement that two equal objects must return the same hashcode and equal is only overridden when the result depends on values of fields.

Comment: @IanRingrose right k. I guess what you say makes sense, throwing in GetHashCode for a mutable object, since it means that the object just should not be used that way. equality in C# is sure messy.

Comment: @DaveCousineau GetHashCode and IsEqual should never have been members of Object as they are not senible for many classes.

Answer (score 11):

Hash code is used for hash-based collections like Dictionary, Hashtable, HashSet etc. The purpose of this code is to very quickly pre-sort specific object by putting it into specific group (bucket). This pre-sorting helps tremendously in finding this object when you need to retrieve it back from hash-collection because code has to search for your object in just one bucket instead of in all objects it contains. The better distribution of hash codes (better uniqueness) the faster retrieval. In ideal situation where each object has a unique hash code, finding it is an O(1) operation. In most cases it approaches O(1).

Answer (score 8):

It's not necessarily important; it depends on the size of your collections and your performance requirements and whether your class will be used in a library where you may not know the performance requirements. I frequently know my collection sizes are not very large and my time is more valuable than a few microseconds of performance gained by creating a perfect hash code; so (to get rid of the annoying warning by the compiler) I simply use:

```
   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
      return base.GetHashCode();
   }
```

(Of course I could use a #pragma to turn off the warning as well but I prefer this way.)

When you are in the position that you *do* need the performance than all of the issues mentioned by others here apply, of course. **Most important** - otherwise you will get wrong results when retrieving items from a hash set or dictionary: **the hash code must not vary with the life time of an object** (more accurately, during the time whenever the hash code is needed, such as while being a key in a dictionary): for example, the following is wrong as Value is public and so can be changed externally to the class during the life time of the instance, so you must not use it as the basis for the hash code:

```
   class A
   {
      public int Value;

      public override int GetHashCode()
      {
         return Value.GetHashCode(); //WRONG! Value is not constant during the instance's life time
      }
   }
```

On the other hand, if Value can't be changed it's ok to use:

```
   class A
   {
      public readonly int Value;

      public override int GetHashCode()
      {
         return Value.GetHashCode(); //OK  Value is read-only and can't be changed during the instance's life time
      }
   }
```

Comment: Downvoted. This is plain wrong. Even Microsoft states in MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) that the value of GetHashCode MUST change when the object state changes in a way that may affect the return value of a call to Equals(), and even in its examples it also shows GetHashCode implementations that fully depend on publicly changeable values.

Comment: Sebastian, I disagree: If you add an object to a collection that uses hash codes it will be put in a bin dependent on the hash code. If you now change the hash code you will not find the object again in the collection as the wrong bin will be searched. This is, in fact, something that has happened in our code and that's why I found it necessary to point that out.

Comment: Sebastian, In addition, I cannot see a statement in the link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) that GetHashCode() must change. In contrary - it must NOT change as long as Equals returns the same value for the same argument: "The GetHashCode method for an object must consistently return the same hash code as long as there is no modification to the object state that determines the return value of the object's Equals method. " This statement does not imply the opposite, that it must change if the return value for Equals changes.

Comment: @ILoveFortran, I don't think what you're saying is correct. The MSDN article to clearly states: "A hash code is not a permanent value. For this reason: 1)Do not serialize hash code values or store them in databases. 2) Do not use the hash code as the key to retrieve an object from a keyed collection. 3... 4...", ie, the HasCode changes during the lifetime of the object and your code needs to be aware of that. If you want to make each object unique with an identifier that never changes in its lifetime, you should use something else.

Comment: @Joao, you are confusing the client/consumer side of the contract with the producer/implementer. I am talking about the responsibility of the implementer, who overrides GetHashCode(). You are talking about the consumer, the one who is using the value.

Comment: Complete misunderstanding... :) The truth is that the hash code must change when the state of the object changes unless the state is irrelevant to the identity of the object. Also, you should never use a MUTABLE object as a key in your collections. Use read-only objects for this purpose. GetHashCode, Equals... and some other methods whose names I don't remember at this very moment should NEVER throw.

Comment: @darlove: One should never use an object which is *going* to be mutated while it is in a hashed collection.  That does not imply that there is anything wrong with using a mutable object in a hashed collection if all references to the object, the collection are held by entities that will refrain from using any of them to modify the object while it is in the collection.

Answer (score 6):

As of [C# 9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9)(.net 5 or .net core 3.1), you may want to use [records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types) as it does [Value Based Equality](https://dev.to/wrijugh/c-9-0-value-based-equality-2n8j) by default.

Answer (score 5):

You should always guarantee that if two objects are equal, as defined by Equals(), they should return the same hash code. As some of the other comments state, in theory this is not mandatory if the object will never be used in a hash based container like HashSet or Dictionary. I would advice you to always follow this rule though. The reason is simply because it is way too easy for someone to change a collection from one type to another with the good intention of actually improving the performance or just conveying the code semantics in a better way.

For example, suppose we keep some objects in a List. Sometime later someone actually realizes that a HashSet is a much better alternative because of the better search characteristics for example. This is when we can get into trouble. List would internally use the default equality comparer for the type which means Equals in your case while HashSet makes use of GetHashCode(). If the two behave differently, so will your program. And bear in mind that such issues are not the easiest to troubleshoot.

I've summarized this behavior with some other GetHashCode() pitfalls in a [blog post](https://vkontech.com/gethashcode-pitfalls/) where you can find further examples and explanations.

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that the original GetHashCode() returns the memory address of the object, so it's essential to override it if you wish to compare two different objects.

EDITED:
That was incorrect, the original GetHashCode() method cannot assure the equality of 2 values. Though objects that are equal return the same hash code.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, when you override the `Equals()` method, it's recommended to also override `GetHashCode()`. The reason is related to how .NET uses GetHashCode in its built-in data structures.

When you store an object in a hash-based collection like `Dictionary` or `HashSet`, .NET uses the value returned by `GetHashCode()` to organize its data. Objects that are considered equal should return the same hash code, providing optimal performance when retrieving objects from such a collection.

If you override `Equals()`, you're changing the definition of what makes two objects equal. So, if you don't also override `GetHashCode()`, objects that you consider "equal" may return different hash codes. This can lead to inconsistent behavior when objects are used in a hash-based collection. They might not be found in the collection, even though you know they're there, because the collection is looking in the wrong hash bucket.

Let's see an example. Suppose, you have a `Person` class and you have overridden `Equals()` to say that two `Person` objects are equal if their `Name` property matches. But you forgot to override `GetHashCode()`. Now, if you add a `Person` object with `Name="John"` to a `HashSet`, and later try to check if the `Person` object with `Name="John"` exists in the `HashSet`, it might return `false`, which is incorrect, because the `GetHashCode()` might be returning the hash code of the object reference, not the `Name` string which you're using for equality comparison.

To avoid this issue, anytime you override `Equals()`, you should also override `GetHashCode()` to ensure it uses the same properties that `Equals()` does. This will help maintain consistency when using hash-based collections.

---

Overriding `GetHashCode()` requires producing a hash code that considers the same properties used in `Equals()`, and is also evenly distributed to prevent hash collisions.

Here is one example of how you might achieve this:

```cs
public override int GetHashCode()
{
   int hash = 17;

   // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)
   hash = (hash * 23) + field1.GetHashCode();
   hash = (hash * 23) + field2.GetHashCode();
   return hash;
}
```

In this example, `field1` and `field2` are the fields that the `Equals()` method checks. The constants `17` and `23` are just arbitrarily chosen 'magic' numbers that often give good results.

You can also use `HashCode.Combine()` in C# 8.0 and later:

```cs
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return HashCode.Combine(field1, field2);
}
```

Remember, the goal of `GetHashCode()` is not to avoid collisions entirely, but to distribute them evenly. Collisions are inevitable because the number of possible hash codes (`2^32` for `int`) is smaller than the number of possible string values, for example. But a good hash function will help ensure a more even distribution of hash code values and reduce the probability of collision, resulting in better performance when using hash-based collections.

Answer (score -8):

Below using reflection seems to me a better option considering public properties as with this you don't have have to worry about addition / removal of properties (although not so common scenario). This I found to be performing better also.(Compared time using Diagonistics stop watch).

```
    public int getHashCode()
    {
        PropertyInfo[] theProperties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
        int hash = 31;
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in theProperties)
        {
            if (info != null)
            {
                var value = info.GetValue(this,null);
                if(value != null)
                unchecked
                {
                    hash = 29 * hash ^ value.GetHashCode();
                }
            }
        }
        return hash;  
    }
```

Comment: The implementation of GetHashCode() is expected to be very lightweight. I'm not sure is using reflection is noticeable with StopWatch on thousands of calls, but it surely is on millions (think of populating a dictionary out of a list).