# How to compare sets stored in IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, set, comparison, ienumerable

For the sake of simplicity I pass along sets as `IEnumerable`. I need to check, whether two such sets are equal. Currently I'm doing it in the following way:

```
if (theirs.OrderBy(t => t).SequenceEquals(mine.OrderBy(t => t)))
    // equal
```

Is there a simpler way?

---

I need this code mainly for series of such comparisons:

```
if (mine."equals"(new[] { a, b })
{
    do sth
}
else if (mine."equals"(new[] { a, c })
{
    do sth
}
else if (mine.contains(a))
{
    do sth
}
...
```

Comment: check out this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630263/c-compare-contents-of-two-ienumerables

Comment: @SaraSaeed Thanks for that link. The problem is, that often one of these will be a constant and the equality will be checked a few times in a row - that's why I'm searching for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could *actually* keep one of them as an `ISet<T>`, you can just call [`SetEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412096%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You could do this optionally, of course:

```
ISet<Foo> setFoo = theirs as ISet<Foo>;
if (setFoo != null && theirs.SetEquals(mine))
{
    ...
}
// Not a set? Use the slower approach
```

You don't have to sort the set though - you could do:

```
if (new HashSet<Foo>(theirs).SetEquals(mine))
```

for example. As noted in comments, this will treat { 1, 1, 2 } as equal to { 1, 2, 2 } though. Only use set operations if you *really* have a logical set.

Comment: Well, I can generally switch to `ISet<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`. My only concern is that though I can pass simple `new[] { ... }` as `IEnumerable<T>`, I cannot do such simple thing in case of sets and I have to use something more heavyweight like `SortedSet<T>`. Or don't I?

Comment: @Spook: Well you've got a trade-off to consider, basically - do you want the post-construction efficiency benefits of sets, or do you want the at-construction efficiency benefits of creating an array or a list. It will depend on how much you do with the collection after creating it.

Comment: And you will lose any duplicates in the original IEnumerable. `So new[] {1,2}` would be the same as `new[] {1,1,2,2}`.

Comment: @astander: Yes, good point. Basically, you should use a set if you want a set, and something else if you don't :)

Comment: @astander Since I treat these `IEnumerable`s as sets, this behavior is actually expected.

Comment: Then why not rather make use of [ISet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of IEnumerable?

Comment: @astander I just tried that, but figured out, that `IEnumerable` is read-only by its nature and `ISet` is not :(

Comment: @Spook: Well, unless you're *actually* protecting against casting, you're not really making it immutable. You could consider using the immutable collections package though.