# Algorithm for testing inequality of ordered large collections

Tags: c#, ienumerable, equality

Ok, I need to test if two `IEnumerable<T>` are equal. The order of the elements *is* important, which means that:

```
{1, 2, 4, 1, 3} and {1, 2, 1, 3, 4} should not be equal.
```

I've seen a few answers on this site explaining how to do this with `linq`: for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630263/c-compare-contents-of-two-ienumerables)

The problem is that I have to repeatedly test for equality of pretty big collections (thousands of elements) that have a high probability of not being equal, so performance is a factor to bear in mind. The way I see it, all the `linq` methods shown in the referred answer (`Count` or `Except`) need to, if I'm not mistaken, iterate through the whole collection which in the general case is not necessary.

I came up with this code, which works reasonably well (I think) and is fast enough. I was wondering if I'm missing some obvious built in way of doing this (I don't want to reinvent the wheel here if possible.)

```
 public static bool IsEqualTo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> inner, IEnumerable<T> other) where T: IEquatable<T>
 {
     if (inner == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException();

     if (object.ReferenceEquals(inner, other))
         return true;

     if (object.ReferenceEquals(other, null))
         return false;

     using (var innerEnumerator = inner.GetEnumerator())
     using (var otherEnumerator = other.GetEnumerator())
     {
         while (innerEnumerator.MoveNext())
         {
             if (!otherEnumerator.MoveNext() || !innerEnumerator.Current.Equals(otherEnumerator.Current))
                return false;
         }

         return !otherEnumerator.MoveNext();
     }
 }
```

Comment: You can use `Enumerable.SequenceEqual` which is implemented similar to your code (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs)

Comment: @CarstenKönig How so? IEnumerable seems like a great idea, as it can stream the values (if implemented in a manner that supports it).

Comment: Please change your title and rephrase the "best and efficient" words as they convey no details. For every case everyone wants "the bestest and efficientest" solutions. However, it strongly **depends on the exact case restrictions**. In your case, the "big collection" and "in order" are what really matters. "best" is an empty word, really. I;d suggest something like "Algorithm for testing inequality of ordered large collections of numbers" etc.

Comment: And I totally back up the IEnumerable. It can be implemented lazily, thus can even work on and compare open database streams without caching the items. What IEnumerable won't give you though, is the simplest and quickest optimistic test for inequality: you will not be able to easily compare the Counts (obviously, if you have both data sets at hand, and if they have different length, they are not equal, job finished). With IEnumerable, the Count will require to run once over all elements to count them, so bummer. `IList<>` could be better here,it would allow you to optimize against diff counts.

Comment: On yet another hand, if you'd you work on open streams of data, you might simply not have access to the Counts/Lengths information, what leaves us with basic IEnumerable doing the job adequately.

Comment: What you have is pretty much the best possible for comparing `IEnumerable<T>` instances, but do they have to be `IEnumerable<T>` intances? Do you have any additional information about the sequences? If you could have any more information tied to them, like the length or the total sum of the items, that would help you to quickly elliminate some matches.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Thanks, changed the title to something more meaningful.

Comment: @Guffa No, my inputs are `IEnumerable<T>`, there is not much I can do down that path. I'm investigating the usual data I will be managing to see how many times equality tests are failing because the number of elements are not the same. If thats the case, maybe paying the price of `Count()` is worth it. Good to know though that the algorithm I have now is as good as it can get. About the total sum, thats not an option. I mentioned `IEnumberable<int>` in my question for simplicty's sake but the real scenario `T` are not numbers.

Comment: @InBetween: Using count could only make the comparison faster if your data has specific properties, e.g. when most sequences are equal from the beginning and most of the length, and differing in length most of the time. You might want to count them in parallel, i.e. using two enumerators so that you can stop as soon as you see that one is shorter. Basically running the same comparsion without the equality check first. You have to know that it's possible to reset the sequences though, otherwise you only have one go at comparing them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically you are looking to short-circuit the evaluation when an element isn't found.

`IEnumerable.SequenceEqual` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567(v=vs.100).aspx)) already does this; proved out by the implementation in: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs (line 806)

When order is important, you should be able to write a simple while loop:

```
int i = 0;
int aCount = a.Count(); //Use `IList` so you can use the property for efficiency
int bCount = b.Count(); //Use `IList` so you can use the property for efficiency

if (aCount != bCount)
    return false;

while (a.ElementAt(i) == b.ElementAt(i))
   i++;

return i == aCount;
```

Your function does basically the same thing, and would work fine.

Comment: Haven't encountered that site before. What it's mainly for?

Comment: @Rahul It shows the source for the vast majority (if not all) of the .NET framework. Very useful when you want/need to know how Microsoft implemented something.

Comment: Yes got it. Was going through the site. Awesome ... +1 for providing that link :)

Comment: Careful: you need to know the lists are the same size before you use that while loop - otherwise, you're going to get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: @Michael Very true, I'll make it safe.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I was thinking on paying the price of `Count()`. I'll be testing real data to see if an important % of equality checks are failing due to `Count()` being different. If thats the case, your implementation will surely be faster and the tests should confirm it. If equalities are failing mainly due to the contained elements, then I'll stick to mine which seems to be about as good as it can get given the options of `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Using `Count()` first will only be faster if you have an underlying type that already knows the length, or of the data exhibits very specific patterns. Otherwise it will only make it slower. Also, you have to know that it's possible to reset the sequences for that to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you will want to frequently compare sequences, I would suggest that you should define a type which encapsulates an immutable sequence and implements `ICollection` along with either `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>` (you might define two types, one of which wraps an `IList<T>` and implements `ICollection` and `IList<T>` and one of which wraps `IEnumerable<T>` and implements `ICollection` and `ICollection<T>`).  This type should override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`, and should have fields for a cached count along with a couple `Int64` fields and an `Int32` field for overall hash codes, and perhaps an `Int64` sequence number field as well.

If client code calls `GetHashCode`, or if determining the number of items in the wrapped collection would require enumerating the items, your code should enumerate through the collection, compute the hash values for each item and use those compute a couple of 64-bit hash values for the collection as a whole, and finally digest those into a 32-bit value suitable for use by `GetHashCode`.  Even though `GetHashCode()` only requires a single 32-bit value, I would suggest computing and keeping more than that, for reasons described below.

When performing an equality test, start by seeing if both objects wrap the same collection.  If so, they're equal.  Otherwise check whether the collections contain the same number of items and if the overall hash codes match.  If neither condition applies, they're not equal.  Otherwise, check individual items against each other.  Note that if hash codes have not yet been computed, it may or may not be worthwhile to compute (and check) them before doing an equality test; some benchmarking may reveal if it's helpful or harmful.  If a collection will get hashed eventually, it's better done sooner than later.  On the other hand, if equality checks on a million-item collection would consistently report "not equal" after simply looking at the first item and nothing else ever needs the hash value, computing it would be a waste.

If two objects are found to be equal, it may be worthwhile to replace the newer object's wrapped collection with the collection wrapped in the older object and make the newer object's sequence number match that of the older object.  Doing this will increase the likelihood that if the wrappers are compared again, they can be recognized as equal without having to examine any items.  Note that there are various other techniques which can be used to help facilitate future equality tests, which involve different memory trade-offs; unfortunately, the approach which would have the best typical-case behavior has some very bad worst-case behavior.  Note also that while any wrapper that caches hash values will fail if the wrapped collections are modified externally, tracking down the causes of such failures may be difficult if the aforementioned reference substitutions are made.

If many unequal collections are going to be compared, being able to early-exit using hash codes can be a major performance win.  In computing hash codes, I would suggest that you use a couple of "independent" methods of computing 64-bit hash codes.  The reason for this is that depending upon how hash codes of individual items are computed, the likelihood of systemic hash collision when using a single hash method may be unacceptably great.  The cost of computing your own hash values is apt to be small compared with the cost of getting the hash values of your constituents, so computing two or three independent hash functions will be a cheap way to guard against systemic hash collisions.