# How to compare a Mongo array that matches all items of another array no matter it's order in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, arraylist, mongodb-.net-driver

I was using the `Equals(obj)` method, but it's not working correctly because the array elements in the database are not ordered. If the order is different, it is not considered a matching element.

I tried [that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50017334/8604967) in two ways:

```
var filteredObj = objects.Find(obj => obj.Elements.OrderBy(x => x).Equals(elements)).FirstOrDefault();
```

```
var filteredObj = objects.Find(obj => obj.Elements.OrderBy(x => x).Equals(elements)).FirstOrDefault();
```

But in both of them I get the following exception:
`Unsupported filter: {document}{Elements}.Equals(value(System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Int32]).OrderBy(x => x)).`
It seems that MongoDb Driver doesn't support that kind of thing.

The method responsible for that:

```
public string GetIdByElements(List<int> elements)
{
    var filteredObj = objects.Find(obj => obj.Elements.Equals(elements)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (filteredObj is null)
        throw new ObjectNotFoundException("Object not found");
    return filteredObj.Id.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You can use the [$setEquals](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setEquals/) operator.

Comment: It seems to be what I need... Do you know if it is available for the C# Driver? Couldn't find nothing related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `Find` query with the `$setEquals` operator as follows. Assuming the MongoDB colection's array filed name `arrayField`:

```
var elements = new List<int>() { 1, 34, 900 };    // input list
var bsonElements = new BsonArray(elements);
var query = 
    new BsonDocument("$expr",
           new BsonDocument("$setEquals", 
               new BsonArray {
                    "$arrayField",
                     bsonElements
                
           })
);

var doc = collection.Find(query).FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(doc);    // doc is of type BsonDocument
```

---

A sample collection's document with an array field: `{ "arrayField" : [ 1, 33, 900 ] }`.
The query in `mongo` shell to match the array elements using `$setEquals` operator (the order of the elements do not matter):

```
db.collection.find( { $expr: { $setEquals: [ "$arrayField", [ 1, 900, 33 ] ] } } )
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. In the documentation it says that "if an array contains duplicate entries, `$setEquals` ignores the duplicate entries.". Is there a workaround to this? I need to make that validation too.

Comment: You want to consider exactly same number of elements in both the arrays as a match?

Comment: Actually I misunderstood it, it won't be needed. Thanks for the help! :)