# Get common keys and common values of two dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda, linq-to-entities

Hi I have two dictionaries of next type:

```
SortedDictionary<string, ClusterPatternCommonMetadata> PatternMetaData { get; set; }
```

The ClusterPatternCommonMetadata object looks like:

```
int ChunkQuantity { get; set; }

SortedDictionary<int, int> ChunkOccurrences { get; set; }
```

First I need the way to find keys of PatternMetaData that is exists in two dictionaries. I find this way:

```
List<string> commonKeysString=
            vector.PatternMetaData.Keys.Intersect(currentFindingVector.PatternMetaData.Keys)
```

Then I need to find common values of the founded keys...

Is there is the fast way (lambda, linq, etc) in order to do such operation

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for just matching keys or matching key/values? Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804367/testing-for-equality-between-dictionaries-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 15):

This is called intersection.

You can get the keys using

```
var data = dictionary1.Keys.Intersect(dictionary2.Keys)
```

If you want to find equal keys and values that are contained within both dictionaries then just

```
var equalDictionarys = dictionary1.Intersect(dictionary2);
```

Comment: So there is no way to get intersected Dictionary<K,V> by keys and values from two given dictionaries?

Comment: @AlexanderBerdichevsky Just to clarify.. You want to get all the dictionarys where both key and value match?

Comment: I want to create one dictionary from two that inside of it would the common keys and common values of keys

Comment: Yes, this is called intersection :) Try the suggestion in my answer please

Answer (score 6):

You can also get the whole Dictionary items which have common keys:

```
var commonDictionaryItems = Dic1.Where(d => Dic2.ContainsKey(d.Key)).ToList();
```