# Given two strings, is one an anagram of the other

Tags: c#

I just started going through "Cracking the Coding Interview" and have the following solution for this problem:

```
public static bool isAnagram(String s, String t)
{
    if (s == "" || t == "") return false;
    else if (s.Length != t.Length) return false;

    int[] letters = new int[256];
    char[] s_array = s.ToCharArray();

    foreach(char c in s_array) 
    { 
        letters[c]++;  
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++)
    {
        int c = t[i];
        if (--letters[c] < 0) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is pretty much the verbatim solution from the book, only in C#, not Java, and with some additional nullchecks.  I also solved the question using LINQ but wanted an additional solution that didn't involve sorting.

Can this approach be made a bit more elegant?  The code works just fine, I just want to know if there is a more elegant or better solution out there.  Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: `char` represents a unicode character in [UTF-16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.char.aspx). There are more then 256 of them (and even if there weren't, there are surrogates to consider)

Comment: What do you mean by 'more elegant'? This is pretty elegant in my book.

Comment: I think sorting and char-counting are the only 2 viable solutions to this problem, and of the second this is a pretty sweet implementation. So yeah, no idea what kind of more 'elegant' solution you're looking for.

Comment: And char-counting is essentially a bucket sort in disguise. There is no solution without sorting ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This code should work for you:

```
public static bool IsAnagram(string s1, string s2)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s1) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(s2))
        return false;
    if (s1.Length != s2.Length)
        return false;

    foreach (char c in s2)
    {
        int ix = s1.IndexOf(c);
        if (ix >= 0)
            s1 = s1.Remove(ix, 1);
        else
            return false;
    }

    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s1);
}
```

**Edit:** Added non linq version.

You also may add some additional checks for null and empty values and move solution to StringBuilder to improve performance but intent of code is clear.

Comment: From OP:
"I also solved the question using LINQ but wanted an additional solution that didn't involve sorting."

Comment: That's just gorgeous :), thank you

Comment: @mynameisneo, thank you for the kind words!

Comment: You can little modify to increase performance
if (ix >= 0)

{
s1 = s1.Remove(ix, 1);
}
else
return false;

Comment: isn't this a O(n2) solution ?

Comment: Not sure why this a more elegant solution than sorting which can be done in either O(n) with Radix sort or O(nlogn) with merge-sort, both are more efficient than this solution

Comment: Hello @Itsik, this solution isn't much elegant but it's exactly what @mynameisneo wanted: `I also solved the question using LINQ but wanted an additional solution that didn't involve sorting.` Please refer to initial question.

Answer (score 4):

As you have asked for more elegant solution, maybe this one fits your needs - more compacted, written as an extension method:

```
public static bool IsAnagram(this string s1, string s2)
{
    if (s1.Length == s2.Length)
    {
        var count = new int[1024];
        foreach (var c in s1)
        {
            ++count[c];
        }
        return s2.All(t => --count[c] >= 0);
    }
    return false;
}

var result = "mary".IsAnagram("army");
```

Answer (score 3):

To properly deal with all Unicode characters (since [`Char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.char.aspx) represents a UTF-16 code unit), I can't think of an efficient way. But I'll try with a *correct* one:

```
public static bool isAnagram(String s, String t)
{
    s = s.Normalize();
    t = t.Normalize();

    if (s == "" || t == "") return false;
    else if (s.Length != t.Length) return false;

    while (s.Length > 0)
    {
        char first = s[0];
        string search = new string(first, 1);
        if (Char.IsHighSurrogate(first))
        {
            char second = s[1]; //Assumed to work - if it doesn't, the input was malformed
            search = new string(new char[] { first, second });
        }
        int index = t.IndexOf(search);
        if (index < 0) return false;
        t = (index > 0 ? t.Substring(0, index) : "") + t.Substring(index + search.Length);
        s = s.Substring(search.Length);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to continue with using an array of counters (`letters`), you ought to use an array that can contain at least 1114112 elements, and you still need to properly process surrogates.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort both strings and compare

Comment: I have a coded answer that does this, I want a non-sorting option

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that comment in your question

Answer (score 2):

How about this non-linq solution?

```
public static bool IsAnagram(String s, String t)
{
    if ((s == null) || (t == null) || (s.Length == 0) || (t.Length == 0) || (s.Length != t.Length))
        return false;

    var ta = t.ToCharArray();

    foreach (char ch in s)
    {
        int x = Array.IndexOf(ta, ch);

        if (x < 0)
            return false;

        ta[x] = '\0';
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Matthew, this is pretty sweet, but it returns true with whitespace added (ex: "dog", "god " should ideally return false).

Comment: @mynameisneo Not sure what you mean - IsAnagram("god", "dog ") will return false because the lengths differ and the first check will therefore fail and the method will return `false`.

Comment: Sorry Matthew, I didn't see the edited code before I posted my comment

Comment: Ahh sorry! Yes, I ninja-edited before I saw your comment. ;)

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary based solution. Decompose each string by counting the char, then do a [Dictionary comparaison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3804852/128662) (note that this method blow my mind):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("jon skeet".PermutationOf("jokes net"));
        Console.WriteLine(new[] { 5, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.PermutationOf(new[] { 5, 4, 5, 2, 3 }));
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsPermutationOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source1, IEnumerable<T> source2)
    {
        return source1.IsPermutationOf(source2, EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
    }
    public static bool IsPermutationOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source1, IEnumerable<T> source2, EqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        return source1.Decompose(comparer).DictionaryEqual(source2.Decompose(comparer));
    }
    public static Dictionary<T, int> Decompose<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, EqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        return source.GroupBy(t => t, comparer).ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Count(), comparer);
    }
    public static bool DictionaryEqual<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> first, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> second)
    {
        return first.Count == second.Count && !first.Except(second).Any();
    }
}
```

Note that you can give a custom char equality comparer, for dealing with uppercase/lowercase problematic.

I gone a little further, by renaming `IsAnagram`, by `IsPermutationOf`. Works for all kinds of list in fact. Pretty useful and elegant this way.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if lengths are equal, if not, they are not anagram
2. Loop over the chars of `t`
3. Check if the current char of `t` exists in `s`, if not, they are not anagram
4. If so remove that char from `s`
5. If the result is empty string they are anagram

   ```
   public static bool isAnagram(String s, String t) {
       if(s.Length != t.Length) 
           return false;

       for(int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++)
       {
           var n = s.IndexOf(t[i]);
           if(n < 0)
               return false;
           s = s.Remove(n, 1);
       }
       return String.IsNullOrEmpty(s);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting and then comparing the sequence works:

```
bool isAnagram = "asdf".OrderBy(c => c).SequenceEqual("fdsa".OrderBy(c => c));
```

Alternatively, you could use a `Dictionary<char, int>` to keep track of character counts (Unicode chars have more than 256 possible values). Also, you don't need the call to `ToArray()` before iterating over the characters of a string.

Comment: To be honest I doubt that, for the size of the strings usually involved, a presort would outperform a stack-based buffer, especially since the sort still needs a `strcmp` afterwards. Would be worth a test hehe.