# Improve perfomance when select list

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have method as below:

```
public static IList<MedicalRecord> UpdateServicePrice(
                         IList<MedicalRecord> mListMedicalRecord, 
                         IList<ServicePrice> listAllServicePrice)
{
    foreach (MedicalRecord medical in mListMedicalRecord)
    {
        medical.mListServicePrice =
            (from p in listAllServicePrice
             where p.MedicalRecordID == medical.MedicalRecordID
            select p).ToList();
    }
    return mListMedicalRecord;
}
```

but it run very slow.
Any one can help me for improve performance of above method?
Thank a lot.

Comment: Have you tried rewriting it imperatively with `for` loops?

Comment: is this using entity framework/linqtosql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a `Join`-based method that should achieve the same thing, but faster:

```
public static IList<MedicalRecord> UpdateServicePrice(
    IList<MedicalRecord> mListMedicalRecord,
    IList<ServicePrice> listAllServicePrice)
{
    foreach (var j in mListMedicalRecord.GroupJoin(listAllServicePrice,
        mr => mr.MedicalRecordID,
        sp => sp.MedicalRecordID,
        (mr, sps) => new { Record = mr, Prices = sps }))
    {
        j.Record.mListServicePrice = j.Prices.ToList();
    }
    return mListMedicalRecord;
}
```

Your code loops through the `ServicesPrices` once for each `MedicalRecord`. Join goes through the prices once, grouping them by the record ID, and then joins them to the correct record.

Comment: Your solution is great !
Thank you.

The time change from 267s -> 90ms

Comment: Golden rule of trying to improve performance: always time before and after to see if it's actually helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You might get significant improvement by replacing the 'where' with a 'join' clause.

Comment: @ssg, this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where

Comment: @tranceporter: thanks I know about the behavior. I wasn't sure JohnC was referring to it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649444/testing-equality-of-arrays-in-c-sharp#comment3006817_649476