# Performance measure (which one is best to use)

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, linq

I have a `datatable` which holds some Id. I want to extract those Id's with comma seperated values. What I tried is:

**With LINQ**

```
int [] strGoalIds = (from Task in dtActionItems.AsEnumerable()
                    select Task.Field<int>("TaskEntityId")).ToArray(); 
string strGoalTagIds = "";
if (strGoalIds.Count() > 0)
{
  strGoalTagIds = string.Join(",", strGoalIds );
}
```

**WITH For Loop**

```
string strGoalIds = "";
for (int i = 0; i < dtActionItems.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  strGoalIds = strGoalIds + "," + dtActionItems.Rows[i]["TaskEntityId"].ToString();
}
```

Can anyone tell me which is the best way to proceed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [For vs. Linq - Performance vs. Future](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893924/for-vs-linq-performance-vs-future)

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise LINQ is slower, as LINQ internally use loops. If you are really working for perfomance go with the for loop. This stack overflow Post might help you [For vs. Linq - Performance vs. Future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893924/for-vs-linq-performance-vs-future)

Comment: check it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893924/for-vs-linq-performance-vs-future

Comment: In the link i provided Check Matthew Watson's answer. that illustrates it with example.