# Inactive Interval of a day in TimeSpan

Tags: c#, intervals, timespan

I have a c# class named `Slot` which only accept values from `0:00:00` to `1.00:00:00` for all its `TimeSpan` properties.

```
public class Slot
{
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }

}
```

I have these values as my active Intervals which don't overlap each other:

```
var activeIntervals= new List<Slot>
{
    new Slot
    {
        StartTime = new TimeSpan(10,0,0),
        EndTime = new TimeSpan(12,0,0),
    },
    new Slot
    {
        StartTime = new TimeSpan(12,0,0),
        EndTime = new TimeSpan(13,0,0),
    },
    new Slot
    {
        StartTime = new TimeSpan(16,0,0),
        EndTime = new TimeSpan(22,0,0),
    }
};
```

Is there any logic to get the other intervals of the day as inactiveIntervals?

In this case i want this result:
 `0:00:00` to `10:00:00`, `13:00:00` to `16:00:00` and `22:00:00` to `1.00:00:00`

Comment: Why represent *points in time* as *time spans*?

Comment: Is it just your example that doesn't happen to overlap or does your system not allow for overlap at all?

Comment: @dumetrulo that is my requirement and i can't help you with that.

Comment: @dumetrulo Probably because there is no "time" data type in .NET

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen my system doesn't allow to overlap

Comment: 1.00:00:00 means 1 day in .NET TimeSpan @dumetrulo

Comment: You will need to find all the "holes" between the slots, should be rather easy with a loop, and you need to consider if you want to include midnight->first slot and last slot->midnight as well.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen You mean looping through every single minutes between 0 and 24?

Comment: Just a note, as not answering the question. Have you considered the longest day of the year (28 Oct 2018 in UK this year), it is 25 hours long.

Comment: No, sort them, then the first interval is from midnight to the first slot, then if the first slot and the next slot has a gap between them, that's also such an interval, and then go from there.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor you are talking about the dst, right? It won't be affecting my system because i'm not dealing with DateTime. But i appreciate your valuable note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below logic. It will work for you.

You can [test it here](https://rextester.com/LJKYFM29788)

```
var activeIntervals = new List<Slot>
{
    new Slot
    {
        StartTime = new TimeSpan(10,0,0),
        EndTime = new TimeSpan(12,0,0),
    },
    new Slot
    {
        StartTime = new TimeSpan(12,0,0),
        EndTime = new TimeSpan(13,0,0),
    },
    new Slot
    {
        StartTime = new TimeSpan(16,0,0),
        EndTime = new TimeSpan(22,0,0),
    }
};


activeIntervals = activeIntervals.OrderBy(x => x.StartTime).ToList();

var inActiveIntervals = new List<Slot>();
TimeSpan start =  new TimeSpan(0,0,0);
TimeSpan end =  new TimeSpan(24,0,0);

for (int i = 0; i < activeIntervals.Count(); i++)
{
    if (start < activeIntervals[i].StartTime) 
    {
        inActiveIntervals.Add(new Slot { StartTime = start, EndTime = activeIntervals[i].StartTime });
    }
    start = activeIntervals[i].EndTime;
}            
if (start < end) 
{
    inActiveIntervals.Add(new Slot { StartTime = start, EndTime = end });
    start = end;
}
for (int i = 0; i < inActiveIntervals.Count(); i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(inActiveIntervals[i].StartTime.ToString() + " - " + inActiveIntervals[i].EndTime.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

One idea with linq:

```
var inactiveIntervals = activeIntervals
    .Zip(activeIntervals.Skip(1), (first, second) => {
        if (second.StartTime - first.EndTime != TimeSpan.Zero) // Get rid of regions that don't have 'gap', e.g. 12:00:00 to 12:00:00
            return new Slot { StartTime = first.EndTime, EndTime = second.StartTime };
        return null;
    }).Where(a => a != null).ToList(); // Filter out nulls

// Insert range from start to first date
inactiveIntervals.Insert(0, new Slot { StartTime = TimeSpan.Zero, EndTime = activeIntervals[0].StartTime });
// Insert range from last date to end
inactiveIntervals.Add(new Slot { StartTime = activeIntervals.Last().EndTime, EndTime = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0) });
```

This uses a trick with `.Zip` where you take a list and then zip it with the same list moved by 1. Then you can compare `EndTime` from one element with `StartTime` from next element.

Filtering regions without gaps is kind of ugly. You have to check edge cases.

Comment: This seems like too costly.

Comment: @Farshan What do you mean?

Comment: Using linq is very expensive than loop [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893924/for-vs-linq-performance-vs-future)

Comment: @Farshan Don't optimize something that isn't a bottleneck. How do you know if this is going to slow down your application considerably? Profile it first.

Comment: because optimisation is my prior concern. But thanks for immediate help

Answer (score 1):

You need to create new instance of `List<Slot>` and then add intervals of day that does not exist in `activeIntervals` list using iteration of the list elements.

```
public static class SlotExtensions
{
    public static List<Slot> GetInactive(this List<Slot> slots)
    {
        Slot day = new Slot
        {
            StartTime = new TimeSpan(0,0,0),
            EndTime = new TimeSpan(24,0,0)
        }
        List<Slot> inactive = new List<Slot>();
        Slot tmp;
        foreach(Slot slot in slots)
        {
            if(day.StartTime < slot.StartTime)
            {
                tmp = new Slot
                {
                    StartTime = day.StartTime;
                    EndTime = slot.StartTime;
                };
                inactive.Add(tmp);
            };
            day.StartTime = slot.EndTime;
        }
        if(day.StartTime < day.EndTime)
        {
            inactive.Add(day);
        }
        return inactive;
    }
}
```

The extension method uses `day`, that is an instanse of `Slot` class and fits full day. Then we add difference between starts of the `day` and iterated slot to a new list and then shift start of the `day` to end of iterated slot. When loop is over the metod adds remainig interval to the list.