# Querying nested lists with LINQ instead of loops

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Lets say I have the following setup

Continent
--Countries
----Provinces
------Cities

A continent contains a list of many countries which contains a list of many provinces which contains a list of many cities.
For each nested list lets say I want to do a check (name length is greater than 5)

Instead of using this loop structure

```
var countries = dbSet.Countries.Where(c => c.Name.Length > 5);
foreach (var country in countries)
{
   country.Provinces = country.Provinces.Where(p => p.Name.Length > 5);
   foreach (var province in country.Provinces)
   {
      province.Cities = province.Cities.Where(ci => ci.Name.Length() > 5);
   }
}
```

How could I accomplish the same efficiently with LINQ?

Comment: Making this into linq will be less readable

Comment: Not asking for readability, I would like to learn the base concept for this type of query as using nested loops in other scenarios wouldn't be efficient.

Comment: If you want to have better performance, i suggest using for loop. [for loop vs link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893924/for-vs-linq-performance-vs-future) refer this

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to understand the LINQ method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efficiently?  In terms of written code, sure, but we'll call that "cleanly".  In terms of execution, that's not a question you should be asking at this point.  Focus on getting the job done in code that's understandable and then "[race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)" to see if you really need to improve on it.

One thing I should caution is that LINQ is about querying, which doesn't mutate the source sequences.  You're assigning the filtered sequences back to the properties and that's contrary to LINQ principles.  The tag shows you're using Entity Framework so it's definitely not a good idea to do that because it uses its own collection types under the hood.

To answer your question, the `SelectMany` extension method loops on the projected sequence.  When it's translated to a database query, it translates to a join.

```
dbSet.Countries
    .Where(c => c.Names.Length > 5)
    .SelectMany(c => c.Provinces)
    .Where(p => p.Name.Length > 5)
    .SelectMany(p => p.Cities)
    .Where(ci => ci.Name.Length > 5)
    .Select(ci => ci.Name);
```

That'll give you the names of all cities where the country, province, and city names are all longer than 5 characters.

But that only gives you the names of the cities.  If you want to know each level of information, extension methods are difficult to use because you have to project "transparent identifiers" at each step along the way and it can get pretty cluttered.  Let the compiler do that for you by using LINQ syntax.

```
from c in dbSet.Countries
where c.Name.Length > 5
from p in c.Provinces
where p.Name.Length > 5
from ci in p.Cities
where ci.Name.Length > 5
```

That will do the same thing as above, except now, all your range variables are carried through the expression so you can do this:

```
select new
{
    CountryName = c.Name,
    ProvinceName = p.Name,
    CityName = ci.Name
};
```

...or whatever you want to do with `c`, `p`, and `ci`.

---

**EDIT:** *Merged the second answer, which addressed questions in the comments, into this one.*

In order to preserve the parent levels through the query, you need to project a container for the parent and the child each time you loop through a collection of child objects.  When you use LINQ syntax, the compiler does this for you in the form of a "transparent identifier".  It's transparent because your references to range variables "go right through" it and you never see it.  Jon Skeet touches on them near the end of [Reimplementing LINQ to Objects: Part 19 – Join](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/31/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-19-join/).

To accomplish this, you want to use a different overload of `SelectMany` this time, one that also takes a lambda to project the container you need.  Each iteration through the child items, that lambda is called  and passed two parameters, the parent and the current iteration's child item.

```
var result = dbSet.Countries
    .Where(c => c.Names.Length > 5)
    .SelectMany(c => c.Provinces, (c, p) => new { c, p })
    .Where(x1 => x1.p.Name.Length > 5)
    .SelectMany(x1 => x1.p.Cities, (x1, ci) => new { x1.c, x1.p, ci })
    .Where(x2 => x2.ci.Name.Length > 5)
    .Select(x2 => new
    {
        Country = x2.c,
        Province = x2.p,
        City = x2.ci
    })
    .ToList();
```

The `x1` and `x2` lambda arguments are the containers projected from the preceding `SelectMany` call.  I like to call them "opaque identifiers".  They're no longer transparent if you have refer to them explicitly.

The `c`, `p`, and `ci` range variables are now properties of those containers.

As a bonus note, when you use a [`let` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause), the compiler's doing the exact same thing, creating a container that has all of the available range variables *and* the new variable that's being introduced.

I want to end this with a word of advice: Use LINQ syntax as much as possible.  It's easier to write and get right, and it's easier to read because you don't have all those projections that the compiler can do for you.  If you have to resort to extension methods, do so in parts.  The two techniques can be mixed.  There's art in keeping it from looking like a mess.

Comment: Awesome that all makes sense, can I select as a new continent at the end?

Comment: Your original code didn't explicitly show the continents so I started at countries.  If `dbSet` is your continents collection, you'll need to adjust things a bit, but yes, you should be able to do that.

Comment: Looking more closely, `dbSet` looks like a single continent, not a collection of them. You'd need to provide more information but I suspect you know enough now to take that up one more level in the hierarchy.

Comment: So I'm curious about what I would need to do if I wanted to use the selectmany method but keep the parent levels. Thanks for your explanation it was very helpful