# LINQ Where vs For Loop implementation

Tags: c#, performance, linq, for-loop, performance-testing

I'm trying to understand C# LINQ implementation and how is it performance against FOR and FOREACH loops.

Every where I see posts of how much better (in terms of performance) is to use a for loop implementation over a LINQ one. [Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893924/for-vs-linq-performance-vs-future), [Example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156059/is-a-linq-statement-faster-than-a-foreach-loop), [Example3](https://mattwarren.org/2016/09/29/Optimising-LINQ/)

How ever, I'm trying to come along with my own POC to see if I can optimize the `GroupBy` and the `Where` operations and I see the opposite. Can you tell me if my implementations can be optimized better?

```
        //Where Implementation (Main Call)
        var students = createStudentList();
        var stopwatch1 = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch1.Start();
        var y = students.Where(s=> s.age == 32);
        foreach(var entry in y){}
        stopwatch1.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("1) TICKS ELAPSED WHERE: " + stopwatch1.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.WriteLine("1) MILLISECONDS  WHERE: " + stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        var stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch2.Start();
        var y2 = WhereManual(students);
        foreach(var entry in y2){}
        stopwatch2.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("2) TICKS ELAPSED FOR: " + stopwatch2.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.WriteLine("2) MILLISECONDS  FOR: " + stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds);



    public List<Student> WhereManual(List<Student> students){
        var filteredList = new List<Student>();
        for(var i = 0; i < students.Count(); i++){
            var student = students[i];
            if(student.age == 32){
                filteredList.Add(student);
            }
        }
        return filteredList;
    }
```

Output:

```
1) TICKS ELAPSED WHERE: 389478
1) MILLISECONDS WHERE: 38
2) TICKS ELAPSED FOR: 654023
2) MILLISECONDS FOR: 65
```

And for the GroupBy I have

```
//GroupBy Implementation (Main Call)
        var students = createStudentList();
        var stopwatch1 = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch1.Start();
        var y = students.GroupBy(s => s.age);
        foreach(var entry in y){}
        stopwatch1.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("1) TICKS ELAPSED GROUPBY: " + stopwatch1.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.WriteLine("1) MILLISECONDS GROUPBY: " + stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        var stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch2.Start();
        var y2 = dictOperation(students);
        foreach(var entry in y2){}
        stopwatch2.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("2) TICKS ELAPSED FOR: " + stopwatch2.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.WriteLine("2) MILLISECONDS  FOR: " + stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds);


    public List<Student> GetStudent(Dictionary<int, List<Student>> dict, int age){
        List<Student> dictStudent;
        return dict.TryGetValue(age, out dictStudent) ? dictStudent : null;
    }

    public Dictionary<int, List<Student>> dictOperation(List<Student> students){
        var dict = new Dictionary<int, List<Student>>();
        for(var i = 0; i < students.Count(); i++){
            var student = students[i];
            var studentAge = student.age;
            var dictStudent = GetStudent(dict, studentAge);
            if(dictStudent == null)
            {
                dict.Add(studentAge, new List<Student>(){student});
            } 
            else
            {
                dictStudent.Add(student);
            }
        }
        return dict;
    }
```

And this is the output:

```
1) TICKS ELAPSED GROUPBY: 865702
1) MILLISECONDS GROUPBY: 86
2) TICKS ELAPSED FOR: 1364863
2) MILLISECONDS FOR: 1.36
```

Comment: Please make sure to properly measure results (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457605/how-to-measure-code-performance-in-net) - run enough iterations to get stable output, skip JIT by running code once, make sure code is not optimized out (I don't think `foreach(var entry in y2){}` can be optimized out but it does not hurt to check). Then [edit] post with numbers.

Comment: Replace `Count()` with `Count`. The first is linq function, the second is direct `List` method.

Comment: @Antonin Though `Count()` ought not to be a significant performance hit, since it's optimised for things like arrays and lists that offer their own counts.

Comment: (to be more specific about `Count` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.8 - "If the type of source implements ICollection<T>, that implementation is used to obtain the count of elements. Otherwise, this method determines the count.")

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica while I generally agree, it makes this very tiny loop about 10x slower in my measurement.

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica In my testing, removing the parenthesis made a 40000 tick difference when iterating over 10000000 items, and was enough to make the manual test faster than linq in the code above.

Comment: For the `GroupBy` comparison, you're using a different type than Linq, which [internally](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Grouping.cs) uses a `Lookup` to get the enumerator. Possibly the underlying type is the bottle neck in the manual test.

Comment: @Rufus Of course it made some difference, since it has to do the pattern matching, etc. to get an ICollection. I just meant that, compared to the other tasks, it probably doesn't make a huge difference (certainly not enough to be the reason why OP's manual for is slower).

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica But in my testing it ***is*** enough to make a difference

Comment: Also, removing the unnecessary assignment `var student = students[i];` makes a very slight improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much of an answer, but since I played with it a little I may as well share.

I did not spend much time looking at the `GroupBy` comparison because the types used are different enough that they may be the bottleneck, and I'm not familiar enough with `IGrouping` to create a new test right now.

I found that if you use the `List.Count` property instead of the `List.Count()` extension method, it saved enough time (iterating over `1000000` items) to make the manual code faster than Linq. Additionally, a few more milliseconds were saved by removing the assignment `var student = students[i];`:

```
public class Student { public string Name { get; set; } public int Age { get; set; } }

public class Program
{
    public static List<Student> Students = new List<Student>();

    public static void CreateStudents()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            Students.Add(new Student {Name = $"Student{i}", Age = i});
        }
    }

    public static List<Student> WhereManualOriginal(List<Student> students)
    {
        var filteredList = new List<Student>();

        for (var i = 0; i < students.Count(); i++)
        {
            var student = students[i];

            if (student.Age == 32)
            {
                filteredList.Add(student);
            }
        }

        return filteredList;
    }

    public static List<Student> WhereManualNew(List<Student> students)
    {
        var filteredList = new List<Student>();

        for (var i = 0; i < students.Count; i++)
        {
            if (students[i].Age == 32)
            {
                filteredList.Add(students[i]);
            }
        }

        return filteredList;
    }

    public static long LinqWhere()
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var items = Students.Where(s => s.Age == 32);
        foreach (var item in items) { }
        sw.Stop();
        return sw.ElapsedTicks;
    }

    public static long ManualWhere()
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var items = WhereManualOriginal(Students);
        foreach (var item in items) { }
        sw.Stop();
        return sw.ElapsedTicks;
    }

    public static long NewManualWhere()
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var items = WhereManualNew(Students);
        foreach (var item in items) { }
        sw.Stop();
        return sw.ElapsedTicks;
    }


    public static void Main()
    {
        // Warmup stuff
        CreateStudents();
        WhereManualOriginal(Students);
        WhereManualNew(Students);
        Students.Where(s => s.Age == 32).ToList();
        var linqResults = new List<long>();
        var manualResults = new List<long>();
        var newManualResults = new List<long>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            newManualResults.Add(NewManualWhere());
            manualResults.Add(ManualWhere());
            linqResults.Add(LinqWhere());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Linq where ......... " + linqResults.Average());
        Console.WriteLine("Manual where ....... " + manualResults.Average());
        Console.WriteLine("New Manual where ... " + newManualResults.Average());

        GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]