# LINQ: Determine if two sequences contains exactly the same elements

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to determine whether or not two sets contains exactly the same elements. The ordering does not matter.

For instance, these two arrays should be considered equal:

```
IEnumerable<int> data = new []{3, 5, 6, 9};
IEnumerable<int> otherData = new []{6, 5, 9, 3}
```

One set cannot contain any elements, that are not in the other.

Can this be done using the built-in query operators? And what would be the most efficient way to implement it, considering that the number of elements could range from a few to hundreds?

Comment: Do you consider `{1,1,2}` and `{1,2}` "equivalent" sequences?

Comment: @Mehrdad, Yes, i would like those to be considered equal.

Comment: By "sets", I assume you mean all elements are unique?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

If you want to treat the arrays as "sets" and ignore order and duplicate items, you can use [`HashSet<T>.SetEquals` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346516.aspx):

```
var isEqual = new HashSet<int>(first).SetEquals(second);
```

Otherwise, your best bet is probably sorting both sequences in the same way and using `SequenceEqual` to compare them.

Comment: I think HashSet<T>.SetEquals was the method I was looking for :-)

Comment: Good answer-- I forgot about SetEquals! If you may have dupes, before sorting you should probably copy the sequences into a List and compare the lengths first-- this saves you the (expensive) sorting or SequenceEqual() operations in case the lengths are different.

Comment: @Justin Grant - I don't follow... You need to remove duplicates before you compare lengths, and this is just as expensive as sorting.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but doesn't this also produce an O(n^2) solution? The HashSet ctor is remarked as O(n) and SetEquals is remarked thus also (if the same equality comparer is used for `first` as is for `second`).

Comment: @JoshGust which makes the whole thing O(2n) = O(n) amortized not O(n^2).  That's assuming a good hash function of course.

Comment: @MehrdadAfshari Thanks for the correction. After doing some additional reading, I think I understand what you mean.

Comment: @MehrdadAfshari Maybe this is taboo on SO, but I'm looking to learn more about this. Can you check my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51775026/4629442 and give me some places to learn more about understanding complexity?

Answer (score 50):

I suggest sorting both, and doing an element-by-element comparison.

```
data.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(otherData.OrderBy(x => x))
```

I'm not sure how fast the implementation of `OrderBy` is, but if it's a O(n log n) sort like you'd expect the total algorithm is O(n log n) as well.

For some cases of data, you can improve on this by using a custom implementation of OrderBy that for example uses a counting sort, for O(n+k), with k the size of the range wherein the values lie.

Comment: So is `O(n log n)` the optimal complexity for comparing non-unique sequences?

Answer (score 7):

If you might have duplicates (or if you want a solution which performs better for longer lists), I'd try something like this:

```
static bool IsSame<T>(IEnumerable<T> set1, IEnumerable<T> set2)
{
    if (set1 == null && set2 == null)
        return true;
    if (set1 == null || set2 == null)
        return false;

    List<T> list1 = set1.ToList();
    List<T> list2 = set2.ToList();

    if (list1.Count != list2.Count)
        return false;

    list1.Sort();
    list2.Sort();

    return list1.SequenceEqual(list2);
}
```

**UPDATE: oops, you guys are right-- the Except() solution below needs to look both ways before crossing the street. And it has lousy perf for longer lists. Ignore the suggestion below! :-)**

Here's one easy way to do it.  Note that this assumes the lists have no duplicates.

```
bool same = data.Except (otherData).Count() == 0;
```

Comment: You could use .Any() rather than Count() - then it won't enumerate every item in the list.

Comment: What if `data = {1,2}, otherData = {1,2,3}`? You should also check the other way around.

Comment: This won't work in my scenario, without checking both ways as suggested by Kobi. And with a few hundred elements, I would be worried about performance for that approach.

Comment: @Kobi, why check both ways when you could just check which one is larger first and then do the except

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to do it:

```
IEnumerable<int> data = new[] { 3, 5, 6, 9 };
IEnumerable<int> otherData = new[] { 6, 5, 9, 3 };

data = data.OrderBy(d => d);
otherData = otherData.OrderBy(d => d);
data.Zip(otherData, (x, y) => Tuple.Create(x, y)).All(d => d.Item1 == d.Item2);
```

Comment: Zip will stop when it reaches the end of either list, meaning {1,2,3} {1,2,3,4} will compare "equal" by this method. You can check the lengths prior to Zip, but you might as well just use SequenceEqual.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, check the length. If they are different, the sets are different.
2. you can do `data.Intersect(otherData);`, and check the length is identical.
3. OR, simplt sort the sets, and iterate through them.

Comment: "data.Intersect(otherData), and check the length is identical" -- you must make sure the length is identical to BOTH other sequences

Comment: @Mark - On the first step you were supposed to check they are both in the same length, so you should be ok. That isn't written very well, I agree. (also, talk about the long tail... over 2 years to get a comment `:)`)

Comment: Yes that's true.  Checking the length so much (since it's IEnumerable) is not necessarily feasible though compared with just creating a HashSet from sequence 1 and comparing it with sequence 2.  Intersect will basically be doing this anyway.

Comment: I liked the simplicity of this method but it uses GetHashCode() to make element comparisons.

Answer (score -1):

First check if both data collections have the same number of elements and the check if all the elements in one collection are presented in the other

```
        IEnumerable<int> data = new[] { 3, 5, 6, 9 };
        IEnumerable<int> otherData = new[] { 6, 5, 9, 3 };

        bool equals = data.Count() == otherData.Count() && data.All(x => otherData.Contains(x));
```

Comment: For a regular array, .Contains is O(N) and .All is also O(N), making this O(N^2). The sort and/or set based options are better if your data set isn't trivially small.

Comment: Also doesn't give the correct answer if duplicates are permitted in the input.

Answer (score -2):

This should help:

```
    IEnumerable<int> data = new []{ 3,5,6,9 };
    IEnumerable<int> otherData = new[] {6, 5, 9, 3};

    if(data.All(x => otherData.Contains(x)))
    {
        //Code Goes Here
    }
```

Comment: It's O(n²) in complexity. Dangerous if you have more than several dozens items in your list.

Comment: Simple, but this will not perform well enough for my scenario.

Comment: This won't catch if `otherData` contains additional elements.