# Compare ColorBlends

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

How can I check if two `ColorBlends` have different `Colors` values?

I tried the following code

```
ColorBlend Blend1 = new ColorBlend();
Blend1.Colors = new Color[] { Color.White, Color.Black };
Blend1.Positions = new float[] { 0.0f, 1.0f };

ColorBlend Blend2 = new ColorBlend();
Blend2.Colors = new Color[] { Color.White, Color.Black };
Blend2.Positions = new float[] { 0.0f, 1.0f };

if (Blend1.Colors != Blend2.Colors)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Values are Different");
}
```

It doesn't work because when the `Colors` values are the same for both `Blends`, it still says they're not equal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check is not correct. You can't compare two arrays in that way.
You have to go through and compare each item to make sure they are equal

Comment: i cant use Loops either because sometimes one blend has more colors then the other

Comment: This answer might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673347/linq-determine-if-two-sequences-contains-exactly-the-same-elements