# Determine whether sets are equal (set composed of sets)

Tags: c#, .net, set, compare, equals

I have two Lists of Lists of **int**

```
var a = new List<IList<int>>();
var b = new List<IList<int>>();
```

Each of them having the following data:

```
var a = new List<IList<int>>()
                {
                    new List<int>() { 1, 2 },
                    new List<int>() { 4, 5, 6 },
                };

var b = new List<IList<int>>()
                {
                    new List<int>() { 6, 5, 4 },
                    new List<int>() { 2, 1 },
                };
```

I want to treat `a` and `b` like **sets of sets** so, upon `a.Equals(b),` it should return true.

How can I do my Equals method?

Comment: You can do extension method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your check needs to be order ignorant, you should check this out:  [LINQ : Determine if two sequences contains exactly the same elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673347/linq-determine-if-two-sequences-contains-exactly-the-same-elements).

A set of sets `IEqualityComparer` implementation might look like so:

```
public bool Equals(List<IList<int>> x, List<IList<int>> y)
{
    foreach(var innerList in x)
    {
        var innerSet = new HashSet<int>(innerList);
        var hasEquivalent = false;

        foreach(var otherInnerList in y)
        {
            hasEquivalent = innerSet.SetEquals(otherInnerList);
            if(hasEquivalent) break;
        }

        if(!hasEquivalent) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please, take into account that I'm not comparing 2 lists, but 2 lists of lists and that I want to determine equality in both levels of the nesting.

Comment: I've updated the answer to account for sets of sets, assuming each inner set has the same fixed size, and that an inner set on one side needs to have an equivalent on the other side

Comment: Sorry, but for my problem I cannot assume that each has a fixed size. See my updated question (the data). It should work with the data in the sample.

Comment: I may have expressed myself poorly. I wanted to clarify that  `new List<int>() { 1, 2 },  new List<int>() { 4, 5, 6 } }` won't be equivalent to `new List<int>() { 1, },  new List<int>() { 2, 4, 5, 6 }}`

I meant to say that the inner sets will look for equivalents in the subset of sets of the same size they are.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it without using linq to check foreach element would be
First create an EqualityComparer

```
class ListComparer : IEqualityComparer<IList<int>>
{
    public bool Equals(IList<int> x, IList<int> y)
    {
      return  x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IList<int> obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

then compare the two elements using the equalitycomparer

```
var equals=  one.SequenceEqual(two,new ListComparer());
```

Comment: Please, take into account that I'm not comparing 2 lists, but 2 lists of lists and that I want to determine equality in both levels of the nesting.

Comment: The code will go like this, it will compare each element of the list one with list two, when comparing listone and listtwo it will use the ListComparer with intern treats the elements of the listone and listtwo as lists and compares them as well as lists, the code could also be modified so it would compare a list of lists of list of lists .......... of lists    by changing                                       public bool Equals(IList<int> x, IList<int> y)
    {
      return  x.SequenceEqual(y,new ListComparer());
    }