# comparing lists of objects

Tags: c#

I have 3 methods that should return the same data. The data is a list of `MyObjectModel` and I want to check that the three lists contain the same data. I thought of serializing each of the 3 lists in json and calculating if the length of the strings are all the same.

Is there a better approach?

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, you need to determine what it means for 2 objects to be equal. All fields the same, same ID, etc. Then you can look at implementing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx):

```
if(list1.SequenceEqual(list2) && list2.SequenceEqual(list3)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer, this seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Does the order of items in the lists matter here?

Comment: @AustinSalonen: no, the order of the elements in each list doesn't matter; as long as they're all there I'm fine. Is there more to it?

Comment: In that case you may want to check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669970/compare-two-listt-objects-for-equality-ignoring-order) out. My answer assumed you wanted sequence (order) equality. (Note that the first answer there is very similar; it just sorts the lists first).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a HashSet to do this.

First you add all items from the first list to the HashSet.

Then you iterate the second list, asking to the HashSet if it contains the item or not.

If all are contained there, then they contain the same elements.

**Example**

```
var list1 = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };
var list2 = new string[] { "B", "A", "C" };
var list3 = new string[] { "C", "B", "A" };

var hs = new HashSet<string>(list1);
if (list2.All(x => hs.Contains(x)) && list3.All(x => hs.Contains(x)))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var isEqual=List<type>.Equals(List1,List2)
var allEqual= isEqual && List<type>.Equals(List1,List3)
```