# Creating a custom equality comparer for IEnumerables<T> when T is IEnumerable

Tags: c#, iequalitycomparer

I want to have a custom equality comparer `IEnumerable`s. using **@PaulZahra**'s [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17109193/1925272), I created the following class:

```
class CustomEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        var enumerables = new Dictionary<T, uint>();

        foreach (T item in x)
        {
            enumerables.Add(item, 1);
        }

        foreach (T item in y)
        {
            if (enumerables.ContainsKey(item))
            {
                enumerables[item]--;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return enumerables.Values.All(v => v == 0);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> obj) => obj.GetHashCode();
}
```

The problem is that if `T` itself is an `IEnumerable`, then `ContainsKey` will check for reference equality, while the point of this equality comparer is to check for value equality **at any given depth**.

I thought to use `.Keys.Contains()` instead, since it can accept an `IEqualityComparer` as an argument:

```
if (enumerables.Keys.Contains(item, this)) // not sure if "this" or a new object
```

but I get the following error (**CS1929**):

> 'Dictionary.KeyCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Contains(IQueryable, T, IEqualityComparer)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'

I am not sure how to approach this. How to fix it? Thanks.

---

**Edit:** Note that this comparer doesn't care about order.

Comment: Side note: cost of iterating an `IEnumerable` multiple times could be enormous (i.e. read all lines in a huge file every time) - make sure you understand limitations and really need that.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks! How else could I compare them?

Comment: Shouldn't `Equals` be public?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani - Yup. Edited, thanks.

Comment: @InBetween - no, the order is not relevant. I Will edit the question to add this information.

Comment: Your `GetHashcode` is wrong, it won’t return the same hash for equal enumerables

Comment: @Sipo you approach is plausible (when done correctly) as long as you understand limitations. There is no way to express "this enumerable is safe to enumerate multiple times" in C#/.Net code... Also remember that not everything can be compared - even simple `{ int i=0; while(true){ yield return i++;} }` will cause you a lot of pain :)

Comment: What is the purpose of this comparer? Are you looking for equal elements in the same order? Does order not matter? Does set equality suffice?

Comment: @MgSam - edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

- As others have mentioned, `IEnumerable<T>` can enumerate forever, so it's dangerous to do this on that interface. I'd recommend using `ICollection<T>` instead- it has a fixed size. And you'll find it will work for most any type you'd want to use anyway.
- Furthermore, I'd recommend using `TryGetValue` to reduce the number of times you need to look up into the dictionary.
- Your code is not correctly keeping the count of each item in the first enumerable.
- GetHashCode needs to take into account every member of the enumerable.

All that being said, here is an adjustment of your implementation:

```
class CustomEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<ICollection<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(ICollection<T> x, ICollection<T> y)
    {
        if (x.Count != y.Count) return false;
        var enumerables = new Dictionary<T, uint>(x.Count);

        foreach (T item in x)
        {
            enumerables.TryGetValue(item, out var value);
            enumerables[item] = value + 1;
        }

        foreach (T item in y)
        {
            var success = enumerables.TryGetValue(item, out var value);
            if (success)
            {
                enumerables[item] = value - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return enumerables.Values.All(v => v == 0);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ICollection<T> obj)
    {
         unchecked
         {
             var hashCode = 0;

             foreach(var item in obj)
             {
                 hashCode += (item != null ? item.GetHashCode() : 0);                
             }
             return hashCode;
         }

     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The problem is that `success` is false even when the values do have value equality.

Comment: @Sipo Ok, I didn't realize that your `T` is also `IEnumerable`, you'll need to add specific handling for that case. Though I think the more important question is what kind of data is it that you're using in this format?

Comment: Thanks. This case is the core of my question, I will be gratful if you could explain to me how to handle it. I have a class called `WorkSession` with `Entrance` and `Exit` properties. This time represent a period of time an employee is at work. An employee can have multiple `WorkSession` in a day, so I have a dictionary where the key is the day of the week and the value is a list of `WorkSession`. This dictionary represents when the employee should be at work every week. Hope I am clear.

Answer (score 2):

To have such recursive comparer you simply need pass proper comparer to `Dictionary` if `T` is enumerable. I think [getting type T from IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906499/getting-type-t-from-ienumerablet) and then equivalent of  `new Dictionary<U, uint>(new CustomEqualityComparer<U>)` (using [Create instance of generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731452/create-instance-of-generic-type)) should achieve what you want.

Notes:

- you must provide correct implementation of `GetHashCode` that matches `Equals`  if you use comparer for any dictionary/`HashSet`. Default `Equals` for sequences is reference compare that does not align with your `Equals`. Note that most implementation of `GetHashCode` depend on order of the items in the collection - so you need to find one that works for sets. I.e. sum of hash codes of each item would do, probably making distribution slightly worse.
- you may want to LINQ set operations instead of doing them by hand. All operations like `Distinct` already take comparers. In case of "sets are the same" you can use [`Distinct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.1) - `x.Distinct(y, comparerBuiltViaReflection)`
- Beware of limitations of such code: not every enumerable can be enumerated more than once (user input, network streams,..) or may produce different result on re-iteration (`while(count < 10){ count ++; yield return random.Next(); }`), cost of re-iteartion many be significant (re-read all lines in huge file on each iteration) or enumerable can represent infinite sequence (`while(true){ yield return count++; }`).

Comment: Thanks! Could you please give a code example of how to accomplish that with LINQ?

Comment: @Sipo I've added all links to questions that you need to construct inner comparer and link to `Distinct`.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to implement your suggestions but I failed. Could you please show me some actual code? I am not sure how to approach this.