# C# Compare Lists with custom object but ignore order

Tags: c#, collections, comparison, nunit, assert

I'm trying to compare 2 Lists (wrapped in an object) containing custom objects.
I don't care about the order, but if list 1 contains "1,2,3,4" then list 2 must **and only** contain those elements. E.g.: "4,2,3,1"

Based on [Compare two List<T> objects for equality, ignoring order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669970/compare-two-listt-objects-for-equality-)
ignoring-order I've used the Except and Any but it doesn't give me the desired results.

If I use `Assert.Equals` it fails, but `Assert.IsTry(list1.equals(list2))` succeeds.

Further more if I remove the Equals and GetHashCode implementation then both tests fail.

```
public class AppointmentCollection : List<Appointment>
{
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {            
        var appCol = obj as AppointmentCollection;

        if (appCol == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return (appCol.Count == this.Count) && !(this.Except(appCol).Any());
    }


    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            //use 2 primes
            int hash = 17;
            foreach (var appointment in this)
            {
                hash = hash * 19 + appointment.GetHashCode();
            }
            return hash;
        }
    }
}

public class Appointment
{
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public DateTime StartTime {get; set;}
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set;}

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var appointment = obj as Appointment;
        if (appointment == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return Title.Equals(appointment.Title) &&
            StartTime.Equals(appointment.StartTime) &&
            EndTime.Equals(appointment.EndTime);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            //use 2 primes
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 19 + Title.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 19 + StartTime.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 19 + EndTime.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}

[Test]
public void TestAppointmentListComparisonDifferentOrder()
{
    var appointment1 = new Appointment(
        "equals test1",
        new DateTime(2013, 9, 4),
        new DateTime(2013, 9, 4));

    var appointment2 = new Appointment(
        "equals test2",
        new DateTime(2013, 9, 4),
        new DateTime(2013, 9, 4));

    var list1 = new AppointmentCollection() { appointment1, appointment2 };
    var list2 = new AppointmentCollection() { appointment2, appointment1 };

    //With Equals/GetHashCode in AppointmentCollection implemented
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(list1, list2); //fails
    Assert.IsTrue(list1.Equals(list2)); //success

    //Without Equals/GetHashCode in AppointmentCollection implemented
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(list1, list2); //fails
    Assert.IsTrue(list1.Equals(list2)); //fails
}
```

Comment: What about dupes. Is {2,2,1} a match against {1,2}?

Comment: @spender, not a match (but this won't matter now because we don't have any duplicates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't state clearly which unit test tool you use. Maybe `CollectionAssert` is the class [`Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.CollectionAssert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.CollectionAssert.aspx), or maybe it is [`NUnit.Framework.CollectionAssert`](http://nunit.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.4.7plus-pdfsg/classNUnit_1_1Framework_1_1CollectionAssert.html), or maybe something else?

So check the documentation of your testing tool, or write here which one you use.

However, it is common for

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual( ... );
```

to check if the collections are the same *in the same order*, while

```
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent( ... );
```

will check what you want. So use the latter.

Neither of the two methods on `CollectionAssert` actually uses your override of `Equals(object)`. To use that, write:

```
Assert.AreEqual( ... );
```

**Edit:** I thought `Assert.AreEqual(exp, act);` would always end up doing `exp.Equals(act)` which would call your override on `AppointmentCollection`. But it turns out we end in the private [instance method `EqualConstraint.ObjectsEqual`](http://nunit.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.4.7plus-pdfsg/EqualConstraint_8cs-source.html), and as one sees it checks if the run-time type implements `ICollection` in which case your override is never used.

Lesson learned: Using `Assert.AreEqual` can be confusing with collections. Use `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` or `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` to make your intention clear. You don't have to override `Equals` on `AppointmentCollection` if you only need it for testing. If you need it for the application itself and you want to test that, write the test with `list1.Equals(list2)` literally to make sure your own override is what is tested.

(In any case the override on `Appointment` is needed, of course.)

Comment: Sorry, it was NUnit. I was wondering why AreEquals and IsTry+Equals gave different results. Because if I want to check in code (and not in the Test) I need to know if the comparison is correct.

Comment: @RvdK Did you see my updated answer? `Assert.AreEqual` is distinct from `CollectionAssert.AreEqual`. Your question is confusing the two. The first one simply calls `Equals` once on the collections. This is calling you override on `AppointmentCollection`. The second one iterates through the collections and calls `Equals` on the individual `Appointment` instances. This does not use your override **on `AppointmentCollection`** (but does use your override on `Appointment`).

Comment: What is the reason that Assert.AreEqual does not function correctly on the AppointmentCollection? Is my implementation of GetHashCode incorrect then?

Comment: @RvdK Your code does not check `Assert.AreEqual`. You only use `CollectionAssert.AreEqual`. I would say when `Assert.IsTrue(list1.Equals(list2))` is OK, then so is `Assert.AreEqual(list1, list2)`.

Comment: If I use 'Assert.IsTrue(list1.Equals(list2));' it succeeds, but if I use 'Assert.AreEqual(list1, list2);' it fails.