# How to remove reverse duplicates in a C# Tuple list

Tags: c#, asp.net, tuples

Say I have a Tuple List like this:

```
    List<Tuple<string, string>> conflicts = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
    conflicts.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Maths", "English"));
    conflicts.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Science", "French"));
    conflicts.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("French", "Science"));
    conflicts.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("English", "Maths"));
```

And I want to check the Tuple List for reverse duplicates and remove them, how would I go about doing this with a loop?

NOTE: by reverse duplicates I mean the recurrence of "English", "Maths" and "Maths", "English"

NOTE: My Tuple in my code is populated using SqlDataReader but the example I used above is pretty close to the way its laid out.

This seems like it would be really simple but it has had be stumped all night

Comment: Do you want to remove both duplicates, or leave one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> conflicts = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
List<Tuple<string, string>> noConflicts = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

conflicts.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Maths", "English"));
conflicts.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Science", "French"));
conflicts.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("French", "Science"));
conflicts.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("English", "Maths"));

foreach(Tuple<string,string> t in conflicts)
{
      if(!noConflicts.Contains(t) && !noConflicts.Contains(new Tuple<string,string>(t.Item2,t.Item1)))
           noConflicts.Add(t);
}

foreach(Tuple<string, string> t in noConflicts)
       Console.WriteLine(t.Item1 + "," + t.Item2);
```

I am sure there are better ways,but it works

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks for this, other solutions may have been cleaner, however yours was the most straightforward for me to understand and use at my current level of ability so I marked it the accepted answer. Take care.

Answer (score 5):

With a custom `IEqualityComparer`

```
public class TupleComparer : IEqualityComparer<Tuple<string, string>>
{
    public bool Equals(Tuple<string, string> x, Tuple<string, string> y)
    {
        return  (x.Item1 == y.Item1 && x.Item2 == y.Item2) ||
                (x.Item1 == y.Item2 && x.Item2 == y.Item1);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Tuple<string, string> obj)
    {
        return string.Concat(new string[] { obj.Item1, obj.Item2 }.OrderBy(x => x)).GetHashCode();
        //or
        //return (string.Compare(obj.Item1, obj.Item2) < 0 ? obj.Item1 + obj.Item2 : obj.Item2 + obj.Item1).GetHashCode(); 
    }
}
```

You can use a `HashSet<Tuple<string, string>>` instead of `List<Tuple<string, string>>`

```
var conflicts = new HashSet<Tuple<string, string>>(new TupleComparer());
conflicts.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Maths", "English"));
conflicts.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Science", "French"));
conflicts.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("French", "Science"));
conflicts.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("English", "Maths"));
```

Answer (score 3):

A rather crude implementation:

```
var distinct =
    conflicts
        .GroupBy(
            x =>
                {
                    var ordered = new[] { x.Item1, x.Item2 }.OrderBy(i => i);
                    return
                        new
                        {
                            Item1 = ordered.First(),
                            Item2 = ordered.Last(),
                        };
                })
        .Distinct()
        .Select(g => g.First())
        .Dump();
```

It orders the items in the tuple so that Maths,English and Engilsh,Maths are the same, then puts them into a anonymous type (calling things Item1/2 again), then relies on the structural equality of anonymous types to perform a distinct, then I just pull out the first tuple from each group.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're misusing `Tuple<T,Y>`. If `{ "Math", "Science" }`and `{ "Science" , "Math" }` are interchangeable, then they're not pairs. You're using it more as a `string[2]`. As an example, in a `Dictionary`, which is a `Tuple<TKey,TValue>` the are meaningfully separate things that do have a proper pair relationship and aren't just lists of data.

Try using something like `List<List<string>>`, which better represents your data, and allows you access to useful `List<T>` answer, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669970/compare-two-listt-objects-for-equality-ignoring-order). Or indeed `List<Conflict>`, where `Conflict` contains a `List`, where order is not important to equality.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ one liner. Gotta love it.

```
var noConflicts = conflicts.Select(c => new HashSet<string>() { c.Item1, c.Item2})
    .Distinct(HashSet<string>.CreateSetComparer())
    .Select(h => new Tuple<string, string>(h.First(), h.Last()));
```

This works by sending everything to a `HashSet<T>` which has the `CreateSetComparer()` method which allows it to do a `Distinct()` regardless of order.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var conflicts = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        conflicts.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Maths", "English"));
        conflicts.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Science", "French"));
        conflicts.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("French", "Science"));
        conflicts.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("English", "Maths"));

        RemoveDupes(conflicts);
        foreach(var i in conflicts) Console.WriteLine(i.Item1 + " " + i.Item2);

    }

    public static void RemoveDupes(List<Tuple<string, string>> collection){
        var duplicates = collection
            // indescriminate which value comes first
            .Select((x, i) => new{ Item= new Tuple<string,string>(x.Item2.IsGreaterThan(x.Item1) ? x.Item2 : x.Item1, 
                                                                  x.Item2.IsGreaterThan(x.Item1) ? x.Item1 : x.Item2), Index = i})
            // group on the now indescrimitate values
            .GroupBy(x => x.Item)
            // find duplicates
            .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
            .Select(x => new {Items = x, Count=x.Count()})
            // select all indexes but first
            .SelectMany( x =>
                x.Items.Select( b => b)
                       .Zip(Enumerable.Range( 1, x.Count ),
                            ( j, i ) => new { Item = j, RowNumber = i }
                )
            ).Where(x => x.RowNumber != 1);
        foreach(var item in duplicates){
            collection.RemoveAt(item.Item.Index);
        }
    }


}

public static class Ext{
    public static bool IsGreaterThan(this string val, string compare){
        return val.CompareTo(compare) == 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid AB/BA ambiguity of representation is having data model, that does not allow them. By imposing constraints You can achieve that, in databases this is widely used approach. If we say that tuple is ordered, no ambiguity can occur

```
public class Ordered2StrTuple : Tuple<string, string> 
{
    public Ordered2StrTuple(string a, string b)
        : this(a, b, String.CompareOrdinal(a,b))
    { }

    private Ordered2StrTuple(string a, string b, int cmp)
        : base(cmp > 0 ? b : a, cmp > 0 ? a : b)
    { }
}
```

Now the task is really easy:

```
var noConflicts = conflicts
    .Select(s => new Ordered2StrTuple(s.Item1, s.Item2))
    .Distinct();
```

The comparison needs to be ordinal to be consistent with Equal, so I removed the generic version I had here. If You only want to do one time deduplication, You can to it like this:

```
var noConflicts = conflicts.Select(t =>
    String.CompareOrdinal(t.Item1, t.Item2) > 0 ? new Tuple<string, string>(t.Item2, t.Item1) : t
    ).Distinct();
```