# Is there a .NET built-in structure similar with Tuple (or a recommended way to build one) that is order invariant regarding the hashcode?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a .NET built-in structure similar with Tuple (or a recommended way to build one) that is order invariant regarding the equality and hashcode?

The code below has the expected ishashequal=false, the structure I am looking for would return true.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Tuple<char, char>, int>();
var x = new Tuple<char, char>('a', 'b');           
var y = new Tuple<char, char>('b', 'a');
dict.Add(x, 1);
bool isequal = dict.ContainsKey(y);
```

Comment: If it would be invariant, then you would get exception for duplicate key.

Comment: @tchelidze: Not when only adding one of the elements, as per the question.

Comment: Yes, in case I would add y too, this is what I would expect.

Comment: You can create your own class, implementing IEquatable<T> and overriding Equals(object) and GetHashCode

Comment: Yeah, right, didn't catch it.

Comment: Definition of a Tuple: A tuple is a finite **ordered** list (sequence) of elements. I think you are looking for a Set

Comment: You might want to look at this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656007/c-sharp-tuple-or-other-multikey-variant-for-dictionary-but-with-permutability

Comment: I think if the order is not important, you can basically use arrays instead of tuples and substitute *containsKey* with linq's *intersect*.

Comment: @melle, yes, that example would work ok, thanks.

Comment: @vc 74, yes, implementing IEqualityComparer would work ok, as in the example that was indicated above. Not quite built in .net, but good enough.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a .NET built-in structure similar with Tuple (or a recommended way to build one) that is order invariant regarding the equality and hashcode?

No. It would be broken if there was.

There's an over-simplification often given of "a hash code of a key must not change", which is wrong. Really, "a key must not change while being used as a key" which the hash code not changing should reflect. If something changes in a way that changes how it compares to other items then the hash code **must** change to reflect that. This mustn't happen while it is used as a key, but that means the key must not change. Otherwise if you created an object, changed it and **then** used it as a key, it wouldn't work.

Okay, so to alter your question

> Is there a .NET built-in structure similar with Tuple (or a recommended way to build one) that is order invariant regarding the equality and hashcode [when the component items are invariant]?

Yes, *Tuple* would be one example. As would *ValueTuple* and anonymous objects composed of the same parts.

> The code below has the expected ishashequal=false, the structure I am looking for would return true

That's something different again. A tuple is a finite **sequence** of a given number of elements. Being a sequence means that order is signficant. We don't expect the tuple `(a, b)` to hash to the same thing as `(b, a)` because `(a, b)` is a different tuple to `(b, a)` and so must not be considered equal and ideally (but not a strict requirement) would not have the same hash code.

Indeed `Tuple<int, string>` can't have the same elements in different orders at all.

`Tuple` represents tuples, but you are describing a use of a *finite set*. The finite set `{a, b}` is the same as the finite set `{b, a}`  because order is not significant.

You need to do one of two things.

Create a structure to represent a finite set of two elements

```
public sealed class FiniteSet2<T> : IEquatable<FiniteSet2<T>>
{
    public T First { get; }
    public T Second { get; }
    public FiniteSet2(T first, T second)
    {
        First = first;
        Second = second;
    }

    public bool Equals(FiniteSet2<T> other)
    {
        if ((object)other != null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Test for same order.
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(First, other.First))
        {
            return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(Second, other.Second);
        }

        // Test for different order.
        return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(First, other.Second)
            && EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(Second, other.First)
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as FiniteSet2<T>);

    // Deliberately matches elements in different order.
    public override int GetHashCode() => First.GetHashCode() ^ Second.GetHashCode();
}
```

Or if you really do need to use tuples, define an appropriate comparer:

```
public sealed class CompareAsSetEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<Tuple<T, T>>
{
    public bool Equals(Tuple<T, T> x, Tuple<T, T> y)
    {
        if ((object)x == y)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if ((object)x == null | (object)y == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x.Item1, y.Item1))
        {
            return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x.Item2, y.Item2);
        }

        return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x.Item1, y.Item2)
            && EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x.Item2, y.Item1);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Tuple<T, T> obj) =>
        obj == null ? 0 : obj.Item1.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Item2.GetHashCode();
}
```

Of course, if the elements are reference types they could themselves be mutated, which would still mutate the otherwise-immutable set or tuple.

(Aside: A recent improvement in the jitter means that it no longer makes sense to memoise `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` as the sequence `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(…)` gets inlined).