# C# : using lambda to GroupBy every collection elements

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, grouping

I have a collection of `Component` and these collections have a collection of `Pax`:

```
public class Component
{
    public IEnumerable<Pax> Paxes { get; set; }  
}

public class Pax
{
    public int Number { get; set; }  
    public int Room { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to group my `Component` collection (which is an `IEnumerable<Component>`) by the list of passenger.

```
var groups = components.GroupBy(c => c.Paxes);
```

Of course, those groups are not expected. Paxes repeated in components have not the same object reference, so I have to compare their properties in the group expression and this is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must implement an `IEqualityComparer` for it:

```
List<Component> components = new List<Component>();
var result = components.GroupBy(c => c.Paxes, new PaxesComparer());

public class PaxesComparer : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<Pax>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<Pax> x, IEnumerable<Pax> y)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<Pax> obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

1. For implementation of `Equals` - You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669970/compare-two-listt-objects-for-equality-ignoring-order) to check that the collections are identical.
2. You'd probably also want to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` of `Pax` class.
3. **Make sure** you implement `GetHashcode` - *cause if hashes are different equals will not be called* - Kirill's comment below

Comment: It is critical to correctly implement GetHashCode method cause if hashes are different equals will not be called.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov - Added your comment to the answer too - good one

Answer (score 2):

You can use this generic collection equality comparer.

```
public class CollectionEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return obj.Aggregate(17, (current, item) => current * 31 + item.GetHashCode());
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }
}
```

And then

```
var q = components.GroupBy(c => c.Paxes, new CollectionEqualityComparer<Pax>()));
```

This of course requires the Pax object to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.