# Comparing lists of objects that contain a list of objects

Tags: c#, list, compare

I have two lists of objects of type A.

```
class A
{
    string X;
    string Y;
    List<B> Z;
}
```

where B is

```
class B
{
    string X;
    string Y;
}
```

How do I check if they are equal in C#, ignoring the order in which the elements are present?

Comment: Compare them how?

Comment: check if the lists are equal or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two List<T> objects for equality, ignoring order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669970/compare-two-listt-objects-for-equality-ignoring-order)

Comment: You might want to start by overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `A` and `B` if you want to compare them on value equality vs reference equality.

Comment: @juharr It might be better to create an `IEqualityComparer<T>` instead of changing the class itself.

Comment: Is this for Unit Tests by any chance?

Comment: @arbitrarystringofletters I do not believe it is a duplicate. This question is in regard to two lists of separate types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to create an `IEqualityComparer<T>` and use an `interface` to link the two classes together.

The `X` and `Y` fields need to be converted to properties to implement the `interface`.

```
public interface IInterface
{
    string X { get; set; }
    string Y { get; set; }
}

class A : IInterface
{
    public string X { get; set; }
    public string Y { get; set; }
    List<B> Z;
}

class B : IInterface
{
    public string X { get; set; }
    public string Y { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create the `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

```
public class ListComparer : IEqualityComparer<IInterface>
{
    public bool Equals(IInterface x, IInterface y)
    {
        return x.X == y.X && x.Y == y.Y;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IInterface obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 * obj.X.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 * obj.Y.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

To check them you can use the following code. This is a simple usage.

```
List<A> list1 = new List<A>
{
    new A { X = "X1", Y = "Y1"},
    new A { X = "X2", Y = "Y2"},
    new A { X = "X3", Y = "Y3"}
};
List<B> list2 = new List<B>
{
    new B { X = "X3", Y = "Y3"},
    new B { X = "X1", Y = "Y1"},
    new B { X = "X2", Y = "Y2"}
};

List<A> list1Ordered = list1.OrderBy(x => x.X).ThenBy(x => x.Y).ToList();
List<B> list2Ordered = list2.OrderBy(x => x.X).ThenBy(x => x.Y).ToList();

bool result = list1Ordered.SequenceEqual(list2Ordered, new ListComparer());
```

If you really didn't want to order them you could use the following:

```
bool temp = list1.All(x => list2.Contains(x, new ListComparer()))
            && list2.All(x => list1.Contains(x, new ListComparer()));;
```