# How to check whether two lists items have value equality using EqualityComparer?

Tags: c#, list, equals

I have an `Account` class:

```
class Account
{
    List<Contact> Contacts;

    // other properties, constructor, etc.
}
```

Using Visual Studio Community 2017, when opening the quick actions menu for this class, I can choose "***Generate Equals(object)***".

Here is the generated `Equals`:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var account = obj as Account;
    return account != null &&
           EqualityComparer<List<Contact>>.Default.Equals(Contacts, account.Contacts) &&
            // checking equality for other properties
}
```

When I try to pass an account with the same list of contacts (same values), the method returns false.

Digging a little bit, I found that the problem is in this line:

```
EqualityComparer<List<Contact>>.Default.Equals(Contacts, account.Contacts)
```

So if for example, I pass the following lists, the above expression will be `false`.

```
var a = new List<Contact>(new Contact("Michael"), new Contact("John")); 
var b = new List<Contact>(new Contact("Michael"), new Contact("John"));
```

And that is understandable since the two lists have different references. How could I change it so it will check for value equality inside the list?

**Note:** `Contact` overrides `Equals` to check for value equality, so checking equality for two different instances of `new Contact("Michael")` returns `true`.

---

**Edit:** If I was not clear, I want the items of the lists to have value equality regardless of their order.

Comment: I think you should also override `GetHashCode` method. Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38434457/2946329.

Comment: Do you want to iterate each list and check that they have identical contents? If they do but they are not ordered the same, are they still equal? Answer those two questions, then try writing some code.

Comment: Also, in addition to the point raised by @MarkLarter, your answer is partially in the question. You probably need to override Equals for the List<Contact> as well, to check if every contact in both lists are present. At a very naive level, it would be an O(n^2) test.

Comment: @MarkLarter I Edited my question so it's more clear.

Comment: @crazyGamer - well, that is exactly what I need help with. Could you elaborate in an answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669970/compare-two-listt-objects-for-equality-ignoring-order

Comment: @MichaelLiu, this is not the question. I need not only to check all the items but also to somehow insert it into the `EqualityComparer`... Thanks.

Comment: @S.Akbari - it seems like this link explains how to remove duplicates... That's not what I need.

Comment: @Sipo: No, you should remove the usage of EquailtyComparer and instead compare the lists directly.

Comment: @MichaelLiu - Thanks. Could you please elaborate in an answer with a code example? I am really new to these things...

Comment: @Sipo You can use that code for finding equality instead of remove duplicates, and change it based on your requirements.