# How to remove duplicate rows from nested list?

Tags: c#, list

I have *nested list* to perform as 2D array:

```
public List<List<float?>> arrayFloatValue = new List<List<float?>>();
```

This nested list has **2000** columns in parent and **20000** float values in child array. Now I want to match *repeated rows* and *remove* from sub list. Below is sample code.

```
//Define capacity
int ColumnsCount = 2000;
int RowsCount = 20000;

//Create object
public List<List<float?>> arrayFloatValue = new List<List<float?>>();

//Initiate parent list i.e. 2000 
arrayFloatValue = new List<float?>[ColumnsCount].ToList();

//Initiate child list i.e. 20000 
for (int i = 0; i < ColumnsCount; i++)
{
    arrayFloatValue[i] = new float?[RowsCount].ToList();
}

//Fill dummy data.
for (int x = 0; x < ColumnsCount; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < RowsCount; y++)
    {
        if (y % 50 != 0)
            arrayFloatValue[x][y] = x + y; // Assign dummy value
        else
            arrayFloatValue[x][y] = 0;     // Forcefully 0 value added for each 50th row.
    }
}
```

Now I have array like

```
//  [0] [0]     [1] [0]     [2] [0]     ...
//      [1]         [2]         [3]     ...
//      [2]         [3]         [4]     ...
//      [3]         [4]         [5]     ...
//      [4]         [5]         [6]     ...
//      [5]         [6]         [7]     ...
//      [6]         [7]         [8]     ...
//      [7]         [8]         [9]     ...
//      [8]         [9]         [10]    ...
//      [9]         [10]        [11]    ...
//  ...         ...         ...
//      [49]        [50]        [51]    ...
//      [0]         [0]         [0] ...
//  
//  And so on..
//
```

Now I want to remove *repeated values* in *each column*. Here in above example I have `0` value as repeated at each row index like `50`th, `100t`h `150`th .... so on. I want to *remove* these rows.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected results based on those sample inputs.

Comment: public List<List<float?>> arrayFloatValue = new List<List<float?>>(); This nested list has 2000 columns in parent and 20000 float values in child array. Now I want to match repeated rows in each row and remove it. I dont have enough code now.

Comment: To be more specific to what mjwills is saying. He's saying, update your question and actually include code snippets of what you're doing, what output you're getting and what output would you like instead. Because right now, we can just guess.

Comment: The number of items in the parent and child lists is not relevant, you can create an example with only a few rows, with each row only containing a few items. What is relevant is what you mean by "Equal" for two lists. Do they only have to contain the same items, or do they have to be in the same order? What if one list is a subset of another? Should it be discarded? That's the reason for providing sample input, output, and describing what equality means in this situation; so you get a good answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517848/distinct-list-of-lists-where-lists-contains-same-values-but-in-different-order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try good old `Distinct` with a *custom* `IEqualityComparer<T>` (we are going to compare *lists* with `SequenceEqual`):

```
public class ListComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>> {
  public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y) {
    return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(x, y);
  }

  public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> obj) {
    return obj == null ? -1 : obj.Count();
  }
}
```

Now `Distinct`:

```
  List<List<float?>> list = new List<List<float?>>() {
    new List<float?>() { 1, 2, 3},
    new List<float?>() { 4, 5, 6, 7},
    new List<float?>() { 1, 2, 3},
    new List<float?>() { null },
    new List<float?>() { 1, 2, null },
    new List<float?>() { null },
    new List<float?>() { 1, 2 },
  };

  var result = list
    .Distinct(new ListComparer<float?>());

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
    result.Select(line => $"{string.Join(", ", line)}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6, 7

1, 2, 
1, 2
```

Comment: As a side note: this can even be made more generic by replacing `float?` with a generic parameter T, so that ListComparer can be used to compare list of lists of any item type.

Comment: @ckuri: Thank you! You are quite right the implementation can be generalized.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you can use a HashSet to filter your list. But you have to define a IEqualityComparer> that checks the equality of the elements.

I did an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            List<List<float>> arrayFloatValue = new List<List<float>>
            {
                new List<float> {1, 2, 3},
                new List<float> {1, 3, 2},
                new List<float> {1, 2, 3},
                new List<float> {3, 5, 7}
            };

            var hsArrayFloatValue = new HashSet<List<float>>(arrayFloatValue, new ListComparer());
            List<List<float>> filteredArrayFloatValue = hsArrayFloatValue.ToList();

            DisplayNestedList(filteredArrayFloatValue);

            //output:
            //1 2 3
            //1 3 2
            //3 5 7
        }

        public static void DisplayNestedList(List<List<float>> nestedList)
        {
            foreach (List<float> list in nestedList)
            {
                foreach (float f in list)
                    Console.Write(f + " ");

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class ListComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<float>>
    {
        public bool Equals(List<float> x, List<float> y)
        {
            if (x == null && y == null)
                return true;

            if (x == null || y == null || x.Count != y.Count)
                return false;

            return !x.Where((t, i) => t != y[i]).Any();
        }

        public int GetHashCode(List<float> obj)
        {
            int result = 0;

            foreach (float f in obj)
                result |= f.GetHashCode();

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Although, I don't recommend you to compare floats. Use decimals instead.

Comment: What is the reason that float not recommended ?