# Choosing a data structure in VB.NET and performing comparison

Tags: python, vb.net

I'm a Python programmer and VB.NET newbie converting an application from Python to VB.NET (3.5).

In Python, I have a function which returns a list of tuples which I run on two datasets with results like this:

```
data1 = [(1,"a",2),(5,"c",7)...]
data2 = [(1,"a",2),(5,"x",7)...]
```

Then I want to check if the two data sets are identical.
In Python I check for equality like this:

```
"Equal" if data1 == data2 else "Not Equal"
```

I want to know the easiest way to structure the data in VB.NET.

It looks like the right data structure for each data set in VB.NET is a List(of Something).

Should I create a Class to hold each data item, or is there a simpler way?  If I do, will I need a custom way to decide if two instances hold the same data?

What is the easiest way to compare the two data sets for equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Tuple(Of T1, T2, T3)` generic type, or make your own class.
Either way, you'll need to create an `IEqualityComparer(Of T)` for the class; you can then check whether `set1.SequenceEqual(set2, New MyComparer())`.

If you create your own class, you can override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` instead of creating an `IEqualityComparer`.

Comment: Thanks. I looked this up and apparently Tuple is new in .NET 4.0.  I've updated to indicate I'm using .NET 3.5.

Comment: Then you'll need to make your own class.  If the items live entirely within a function, you can also use an anonymous type.  (In which case you wouldn't need an `IEqualityComparer`, since anonymous types implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd create a small class to hold each item, then use List(Of ItemType) to track the lists. 
As for comparing the two lists for equality, see here
   [Comparing two collections for equality irrespective of the order of items in them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098/comparing-two-collections-for-equality)