# Different results for comparing Array[][] with SequenceEqual() and custom method

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, equals

can someone explain me why I do get different results?

```
bool result = true;
for (int row = 0; row < State.Rows; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < State.Cols; col++)
    {
         if (map[row][col] != other.map[row][col])
       //if (!map[row][col].Equals(other.map[row][col]))
             result = false;
    }
}
bool sequenceEqual = map.SequenceEqual(other.map);

//result = true
//sequenceEqual = false
```

[I overwrote `Equals()`, `GetHashCode()`, `==` and `!=` for the type to be compared](http://pastebin.com/FJpTCXtG). I also tried the `CollectionComparer` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098/comparing-two-collections-for-equality/3790621#3790621) answer, and got the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're not equivalent.

`SequenceEqual` uses `Equals` for every element of a sequence. Since `map` is a two dimensional array, each "element" is actually a row, and that means that it's the `Equals` method of `Array` that ends up being called.

Your method compares each element directly using `!=`, which *is* what you want.

A solution would to supply a custom equality comparer to SequenceEquals. Said comparer would then call SequenceEquals again.

Comment: Thanks, [this](http://pastebin.com/iCTpDGJv) now does get the same result. I somehow thought sequenceEqual does compare only all the child elements.

Comment: Well, it does, but using `Equals`. The problem is that `Array.Equals` does not.

Answer (score 2):

### Completely rewritten answer

First of all, the two ways to compare do *entirely* different things.

The manual comparison:

- compares all `Rows * Cols` items in your array
- compares using reference equality (unless the item type overrides `==` and `!=`)

The `SequenceEqual` comparison:

- compares only items directly in each array; this means it compares `Rows` arrays with other arrays!
- compares by calling `object.Equals`

The result discrepancy stems from the fact that `SequenceEqual` boils down to:

```
if(!oneArray.Equals(anotherArray)) {
    return false;
}
```

[That's a reference equality check](http://ideone.com/GPho3). Which means that unless `map` and `other.map` are arrays of reference-identical sub-arrays, `SequenceEqual` will return `false`.

**[Live proof](http://ideone.com/7Wy5T)**.

Comment: As you can see I tried both and overwrote the implementation for Equals and the Operators, the result didn't change.

Comment: @BeatMe: What do you mean "overwrote the implementation"? Overwrote to do what?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FJpTCXtG this is the implementation for the Type that's compared