# do I need to override Equal?

Tags: c#, overriding

I've read some stuff about overriding Equal and GetHashcode but do I need it when just having a simple own Equal method like below?

And if I do have to override it:

Why is that? - Should I use Id.GetHashCode() when overriding GetHashCode()?

```
public class Foo {
    public Guid Id { get; } = new Guid();

    public bool Equal(Foo other) {
        if (other == null) return false;
        return Id == other.Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Muds but my code above doesnt override Equals? It's just a new method?

Comment: If there are no additional conventions then you don't really need to but I don't see a reason to reinvent the wheel especially since it won't work in conjunction with all the default implementation of comparing two instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks like you want to implement [`IEquatable<Foo>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx) for your object. And MSDN advice to oveeride [`Object.Equals()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

> If you implement IEquatable, you should also override the base
>   class implementations of Object.Equals(Object) and GetHashCode so that
>   their behavior is consistent with that of the IEquatable.Equals
>   method. If you do override Object.Equals(Object), your overridden
>   implementation is also called in calls to the static
>   Equals(System.Object, System.Object) method on your class. In
>   addition, you should overload the op_Equality and op_Inequality
>   operators. This ensures that all tests for equality return consistent
>   results.

Comment: Thank you. Just one question..What do I return when overriding GetHashCode()? Id.GetHashCode()?

Comment: Overriding GetHashCode is another not simple question. For a type with one property you can return just Id.GetHashCode. See also this question and answer about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode

Answer (score 1):

Another pointer to your solution can be found here - It explains what all are your options -- [please have a read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709088/when-should-a-net-class-override-equals-when-should-it-not)

> Typically, you implement value equality when objects of the type are
>   expected to be added to a collection of some sort, or when their
>   primary purpose is to store a set of fields or properties. You can
>   base your definition of value equality on a comparison of all the
>   fields and properties in the type, or you can base the definition on a
>   subset.