# Can't execute overloaded method

Tags: c#-4.0, overriding, overloading

Give then following Class declaration:

```
   class Employee {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In Equals(Object)");

            if (obj is Employee)
                if (this.Name == (obj as Employee).Name && this.Age == (obj as Employee).Age)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            else
                return false;
        }

        public bool Equals(Employee obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In Equals(Employee)");

            return this.Equals(obj as Object);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return base.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to use Employee.Equals(Employee) but for some reason it doesn't work:

```
    private static void CompareObjects(Object a, Object b)
    {        
        if (a.Equals(b as Employee)) Console.WriteLine("a.Equals(b) returns true");
        else Console.WriteLine("a.Equals(b) returns false");
    }
```

As I'm casting b as Employee, I was expecting that Employee.Equals(Employee) would be called, since it matches the signature better then Employee.Equals(Object), but the latter is being called instead. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In

```
private static void CompareObjects(Object a, Object b)
```

You use

```
a.Equals
```

However `a` is of type Object, so you're using Object.Equals().  *You are calling the Equals() method of `a`, not of `b`*.

If you expect both `a` and `b` to be of type `Employee` you could write

```
if (((Employee)a).Equals(b)) Console.WriteLine("a.Equals(b) returns true");
```

or

```
if ((a as Employee).Equals(b)) Console.WriteLine("a.Equals(b) returns true");
```

However, either variant will throw an Exception of `a` is not of type Employee.

Instead, consider

```
Employee aEmployee = a as Employee;
if (aEmployee != null) 
{
    if (aEmployee.Equals(b)) Console.WriteLine("a.Equals(b) returns true");
}
```

**UPDATE**

The signature of your Equals method is not correct if your intent is to override `Object.Equals(object o)`. Your method `Employee.Equals(Employee e)` will still not be called as written.  I would recommend the following pattern if you want to override `Object.Equals(object o)` and if you want things that are not employees never to be equal to things that are employees.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    // If the references are equal, objects must be equal
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;

    Employee other = obj as Employee;

    // obj is not able to be cast to Employee, no need to compare further
    if (other == null) return false;

    // Here, implement the checks you need to compare two 
    // Employee instances for equality
    return this.FirstName == other.FirstName /* && etc. */;
}
```

Note that whenever you override the semantics of `Equals()` you almost certainly want to override `GetHashCode()` as well.  See

[Simplify Overriding Equals(), GetHashCode() in C# for Better Maintainability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707918/simplify-overriding-equals-gethashcode-in-c-sharp-for-better-maintainabilit)

Comment: Updated response.  The current implementation of Equals is probably not doing what you hope.

Answer (score 0):

change the condition from this 
`if (a.Equals(b as Employee))`
to

```
if ((Employee)a.Equals(b as Employee))
```