# Check if two list have same elements in a single evaluation

Tags: c#, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing two collections for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098/comparing-two-collections-for-equality)

I have two lists

```
List<int> Foo = new List<int>(){ 1, 2, 3 };
```

and

```
List<int> Bar = new List<int>(){ 2, 1 };
```

To find out if they have same elements or not I did

```
if(Foo.Except(Bar).Any() || Bar.Except(Foo).Any())
{
    //Do Something
}
```

but this requires two bool evaluations. First it does `Foo.Except(Bar).Any()` and then `Bar.Except(Foo).Any()`. Is there a way to do this in single evaluation?

Comment: What is expected result - to find if there is any same element in both collections, or to find if all elements in collections are same (but possibly in different order)?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: order is not important. just to check if any element is there in Foo and not in Bar or is in Bar and not in Foo.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You don't have to check it twice.
Just do something like this (pay attention to Foo, it can be null and throw the related exception)

```
if(Foo.Intersect(Bar).Any())
{
    //Do Something
}
```

You might also want to check first you have to check if one of those lists or both are empty or null.. but only if that situation has any particular value for you.

Comment: It returns true for given example, but should be false

Comment: I don't think this is what the poster wants. It will let you know if there are any elements that are shared between the two, not if all the elements are shared.

Comment: It will return true if Foo has "shared" elements with Bar (at least one)

Comment: its going in if even if lists contains same elements in same order.

Comment: @Nikhil Agrawal what do you mean by "its going in if even if lists contains.."? I don't get it

Answer (score 1):

```
        var sharedCount = Foo.Intersect(Bar).Count();
        if (Foo.Distinct().Count() > sharedCount || Bar.Distinct().Count() > sharedCount)
        {
            // there are different elements
        }
        {
            // they contain the same elements
        }
```

Comment: `Union` applies `Distinct` to result. Thus count may not be same if initial sequences had non-distinct elements