# Compare two collections

Tags: c#, reflection, collections, compare, observablecollection

I searched for solutions of my problem but i guess i try the wrong keywords again.
I want to compare two ObservableCollections.
Equals and SequenceEqual did not work.

I've wrote some kind of compare method using reflection:

```
var properties = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties();
for (var i = 0; i < list1.Count(); i++)
{
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var value1 = property.GetValue(list1[i]);
        var value2 = property.GetValue(list2[i]);

        if (value1 != value2)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

value1 and value2 are both 'true' but it jumps into the return statement.

Ofcourse i could do it manually with each property of MyClass but that ist not really comfortable.
Hope you can tell me where my mistake is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing two collections for equality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098/comparing-two-collections-for-equality)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value1` and `value2` are boxed `object`s.
`==` will always compare them by reference.

Instead, you should check `if (Equals(value1, value2))`, which will compare them by value.
Specifically, it will call the overridden `value1.Equals(value2)`, after appropriate null checks.