# Is there any built in collection type or IEqualityComparer<T> for collection which bases equality on the items in it?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, equality, iequalitycomparer

Is there any built in collection type (`IEnumerable<S>`) or `IEqualityComparer<T>` for an `IEnumerable<S>` **in the framework** that has it's `Equals` (and `GetHashCode` accordingly) defined by the equality of the items in it?

Something like:

```
var x = new SomeCollection { 1, 2, 3 };
var y = new SomeCollection { 1, 2, 3 };

// so that x.Equals(y) -> true 
// and x.Shuffle().Equals(y) -> false
```

Or a

```
class SomeComparer<T> : EqalityComparer<IEnumerable<T>> { }

// so that for 
var x = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var y = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
// gives
// new SomeComparer<int>().Equals(x, y) -> true 
// new SomeComparer<int>().Equals(x.Shuffle(), y) -> false
```

? My question is, is there something in the framework that behaves like `SomeCollection` or `SomeComparer<T>` as shown in the code?

Why I need it: **because I have a case for a `Dictionary<Collection, T>` where the `Key` part should be a collection and its equality is based on its entries**.

Requirements:

1. Collection need be only a simple enumerable type with `Add` method
2. Order of items is important
3. Duplicate items can exist in the collection

**Note:** I can write one my own, it's trivial. There are plenty of questions on SO helping with that. I'm asking is there a class in the framework itself.

Comment: It seems a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098/comparing-two-collections-for-equality-irrespective-of-the-order-of-items-in-the)

Comment: @wdosanjos not at all. I just went through that link. That question is about how to compare any two collections for equality. My question is, is there a collection that does it by itself. Furthermore, in the linked question, order doesn't matter.

Comment: Are you looking for [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @Jon, no. I will make my question clearer.

Comment: The comparer you get from `HashSet<T>.CreateSetComparer()` comes close to what you're asking for, except that for obvious reasons, a hash set does not preserve order of items.

Comment: @hvd, thanks nevertheless, learned something new! :) Actually too lazy to reinvent wheel if there is something already existing..

Comment: No, there is no such class in the framework.

Comment: No, there is none. You'd be better off implement your own anyway and specialize for your collections. Reason - you'll need to make it comparison to be fast and hence modify/wrap collection to something that has constant-time GetHashCode computation (and preferably protect collections used as keys from modification). So you'll need custom comparer code to tie with that collection/wrapper class.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep it simple. Just use the Dictionary ctor that takes in a specialized IEqualityComparer (just implement your equality logic in a comparer) and you are good to go. No need for special collection types and so on...

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132074.aspx)

Comment: See supercat's answer. Special collection will be better here for efficiency :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can, it may be better to define your own immutable collection class which accepts an `IEqualityComparer<T>` as a constructor parameter, and have its `Equals` and `GetHashCode()` members chain to those of the underlying collection, than to try to define an `IEqualityComparer<T>` for the purpose.  Among other things, your immutable collection class would be able to cache its own hash value, and possibly the hash values for the items contained therein.  This would accelerate not only calls to `GetHashCode()` on the collection, but also comparisons between two collections.  If two collections' hashcodes are unequal, there's no point in checking anything further; even if two collections' hashcodes are equal, it may be worthwhile to check that the hashcodes of corresponding items match before testing the items themselves for equality [note that in general, using a hash-code test as an early exit before checking equality is not particularly helpful, because the slowest `Equals` case (where the items match) is the one where hash codes are going to match anyway; here, however, if all but the last item match, testing the hash code of the items may find the mismatch before one has spent time inspecting each item in detail.

Starting in .NET 4.0, it became possible to write an `IEqualityComparer<T>` which could achieve the performance advantage of an immutable collection class which caches hash values, by using a `ConditionalWeakTable` to map collections to objects which would cache information about them.  Nonetheless, unless one is unable to use a custom immutable-collection class, I think such a class would probably be better than an `IEqualityComparer<T>` in this scenario anyway.

Comment: `even if two collections' hashcodes are equal, it may be worthwhile to check that the hashcodes of corresponding items match before testing the items themselves for equality` I believe checking for equality of items in the collection will be more efficient than checking for their hash. Is hash computation generally (I mean for most general cases) faster than direct equality check?

Comment: @nawfal: If an object has not had its hash code computed since the last time it was modified, computing the hash code will generally be more expensive than comparing the item for equality.  If the object will be compared with exactly one other object and never compared to anything else ever again, the extra effort would be wasted.  On the other hand, if objects for which hash code computation would be expensive cache their hash values, then hash-code comparisons after the first will be relatively cheap.  The extra cost for comparisons after the first will thus be slight, and...

Comment: ...the time that is typically required to compare things that are almost, but not quite, equal may be greatly reduced.  The benefits of comparing cached hash codes will depend in the frequency with which nearly-equal items are compared.  Many applications won't perform many such comparisons, but the benefits from each one can be very significant; if an application happens to do many such comparisons, the overall benefit can be really huge.

Comment: I do get the benefit of caching hash values which is what dictionaries do. My point is, when comparing two Collection<T>s which have their own hash cached (like you recommend) if the hashes are equal, then comparing the items in the collection itself will be easier, than comparing the hashes of the items. Most generic .NET objects dont have hashes cached. They all get computed when `GetHashCode` is called.

Comment: @nawfal: Most .NET generic types are mutable, and base equality on identity rather than content.  Efficient use of immutable nested collections in things like dictionaries, however, requires that objects with expensive-to-calculate hash codes cache them.  If code has a collection that contains certain objects, and wants to construct from that a collection that contains those objects plus one more, then if nothing did any hash-code caching, calling `GetHashCode` once on each of the outer collections would result in each inner object having to compute its hash code twice.

Comment: Hmm, I get you. It will depend on what the user wants to optimize on, memory or cpu.

Comment: If an object is large enough that hashing might take awhile, the cost of an extra four bytes to hold a cached hash value is likely to be trivial by comparison.  A more important question is how likely it is that a hash value will be needed zero times, exactly once, or more than once.  Reserving space for a cached hash value will add a slight cost if it's never needed, and a slightly bigger cost if it's needed exactly once; it will pay off when the hash is needed more than once; in some cases, even "twice" may offer a big payoff, and more than twice a huge one.

Answer (score 0):

I do not beleive that such a thing exists. I had a need to compare two dictionary's contents for equality and wrote this awhile back.

```
public class DictionaryComparer<TKey, TValue> : EqualityComparer<IDictionary<TKey, TValue>>
{
    public DictionaryComparer()
    {
    }
    public override bool Equals(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> x, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> y)
    {
        // early-exit checks
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;

        if (null == x || y == null)
            return false;

        if (x.Count != y.Count)
            return false;

        // check keys are the same
        foreach (TKey k in x.Keys)
            if (!y.ContainsKey(k))
                return false;

        // check values are the same
        foreach (TKey k in x.Keys)
        {
            TValue v = x[k];
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(v, null))
                return object.ReferenceEquals(y[k], null);

            if (!v.Equals(y[k]))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return 0;

        int hash = 0;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> pair in obj)
        {
            int key = pair.Key.GetHashCode(); // key cannot be null
            int value = pair.Value != null ? pair.Value.GetHashCode() : 0;
            hash ^= ShiftAndWrap(key, 2) ^ value;
        }

        return hash;
    }

    private static int ShiftAndWrap(int value, int positions)
    {
        positions = positions & 0x1F;

        // Save the existing bit pattern, but interpret it as an unsigned integer. 
        uint number = BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), 0);
        // Preserve the bits to be discarded. 
        uint wrapped = number >> (32 - positions);
        // Shift and wrap the discarded bits. 
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes((number << positions) | wrapped), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems useful, but why loop through the keys of x twice? Couldn't you merge the checking of whether y has each key of x with the checks for their associated values in one loop?

Comment: I cant use this though, cos dictionaries are not about *order*.

Comment: This is very inefficient as well. Why two loops as @ledbutter says. Why are you enumerating the keys alone and then doing lookup, rather enumerate the whole dictionary? Also you can avoid boxing of values in case they are value types.

Comment: @nawful because if dictionaries don't share keys they are not equal so inequality can be short circuited without retrieving and comparing values

Comment: @dkackman its a good point only if you're not retrieving values in the second loop, which is not. You're doing all the same lookup again. `y.ContainsKey(key)` is just the same lookup as `y[key]`, just that in the second case the value is returned. If you're enumerating the dictionary itself, you can altogether avoid the `x[key]` lookup and in one loop!. Kindly tag me as `@nawfal` so that Im notified of your replies.