# C# Compare two strongly typed list

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, icollection

I have strongly list with data and I want to find the difference in data. I have used EXCEPT but I am getting all the result where I only expect to receive

```
expectedEmailValidationDtoList.Add(new EmailValidationDto { EmailAddress = "testemail889@hotmail.com", IsEmailValid = false, ValidityChecked = true });
```

I want to achieve the following points;

1- If both list data equal or not?
2- the difference in records

### Email Class

```
public class EmailValidationDto
{   
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public bool IsEmailValid { get; set; }
    public bool ValidityChecked { get; set; }
}
```

### List

```
var expectedEmailValidationDtoList = new List<EmailValidationDto>();

        expectedEmailValidationDtoList.Add(new EmailValidationDto { EmailAddress = "Myemail@hotmail.com", IsEmailValid = true, ValidityChecked = true });
        expectedEmailValidationDtoList.Add(new EmailValidationDto { EmailAddress = "TestEmail009@hotmail.com", IsEmailValid = true, ValidityChecked = true });
        expectedEmailValidationDtoList.Add(new EmailValidationDto { EmailAddress = "devOps@hotmail.com", IsEmailValid = true, ValidityChecked = true });
        expectedEmailValidationDtoList.Add(new EmailValidationDto { EmailAddress = "testemail", IsEmailValid = false, ValidityChecked = true });
        expectedEmailValidationDtoList.Add(new EmailValidationDto { EmailAddress = "testemail2@hotmail", IsEmailValid = false, ValidityChecked = true });
        expectedEmailValidationDtoList.Add(new EmailValidationDto { EmailAddress = "testemail3.com", IsEmailValid = false, ValidityChecked = true });
        expectedEmailValidationDtoList.Add(new EmailValidationDto { EmailAddress = "ccccc.com", IsEmailValid = false, ValidityChecked = true });
        expectedEmailValidationDtoList.Add(new EmailValidationDto { EmailAddress = "testemail889@hotmail.com", IsEmailValid = false, ValidityChecked = true });

        var expectedEmailValidationDtoList2 = new List<EmailValidationDto>();

        expectedEmailValidationDtoList2.Add(new EmailValidationDto { EmailAddress = "khurram@hotmail.com", IsEmailValid = true, ValidityChecked = true });
        expectedEmailValidationDtoList2.Add(new EmailValidationDto { EmailAddress = "TestEmail009@hotmail.com", IsEmailValid = true, ValidityChecked = true });
        expectedEmailValidationDtoList2.Add(new EmailValidationDto { EmailAddress = "devOps@hotmail.com", IsEmailValid = true, ValidityChecked = true });
        expectedEmailValidationDtoList2.Add(new EmailValidationDto { EmailAddress = "testemail", IsEmailValid = false, ValidityChecked = true });
        expectedEmailValidationDtoList2.Add(new EmailValidationDto { EmailAddress = "testemail2@hotmail", IsEmailValid = false, ValidityChecked = true });
        expectedEmailValidationDtoList2.Add(new EmailValidationDto { EmailAddress = "testemail3.com", IsEmailValid = false, ValidityChecked = true });
        expectedEmailValidationDtoList2.Add(new EmailValidationDto { EmailAddress = "ccccc.com", IsEmailValid = false, ValidityChecked = true });


  var d1 = expectedEmailValidationDtoList.Except(expectedEmailValidationDtoList2).ToList();
  var d2 = expectedEmailValidationDtoList2.Except(expectedEmailValidationDtoList).ToList();
```

Comment: Unless you override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, or provide an `IEqualityComparer<EmailValidationDto>`, you'll be comparing items in terms of references, which I suspect isn't what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing two collections for equality irrespective of the order of items in them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098/comparing-two-collections-for-equality-irrespective-of-the-order-of-items-in-the)

Comment: I am not what is missing from the puzzle, I have followed the Connell approach and getting the same result  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098/comparing-two-collections-for-equality-irrespective-of-the-order-of-items-in-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Where() and Any() like below for comparing the 2 lists:

```
    var d1 = expectedEmailValidationDtoList1
        .Where(email1 => !expectedEmailValidationDtoList2
            .Any(email2 => email1.EmailAddress
                .Equals(email2.EmailAddress, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
    var d2 = expectedEmailValidationDtoList2
        .Where(email1 => !expectedEmailValidationDtoList1
            .Any(email2 => email1.EmailAddress
                .Equals(email2.EmailAddress, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
```

Or use the All()

```
    var d21 = expectedEmailValidationDtoList1
        .Where(email1 => expectedEmailValidationDtoList2
            .All(email2 => !email1.EmailAddress
                .Equals(email2.EmailAddress, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
    var d22 = expectedEmailValidationDtoList2
        .Where(email1 => expectedEmailValidationDtoList1
            .All(email2 => !email1.EmailAddress
                .Equals(email2.EmailAddress, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
```