# IEqualityComparer using list of string as comparer

Tags: c#, iequalitycomparer

I'm attempting to setup an IEqualityComparer that uses a list of string as the comparing property.

When using Except and Intersect in the 2 lines of code below, all records are seen as 'new' and none are recognized as 'old'.

```
List<ExclusionRecordLite> newRecords = currentRecords.Except(historicalRecords, new ExclusionRecordLiteComparer()).ToList();
List<ExclusionRecordLite> oldRecords = currentRecords.Intersect(historicalRecords, new ExclusionRecordLiteComparer()).ToList();
```

This is my IEqualityComparer class (Words is a List)

```
public class RecordComparer : IEqualityComparer<Record>
{
    public bool Equals(Record x, Record y)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;

        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        return x.Words.SequenceEqual(y.Words);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Record obj)
    {
        return new { obj.Words }.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `GetHashCode`  is incorrect. Use one like this:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    if(Words == null) return 0;
    unchecked
    {
        int hash = 19;
        foreach (var word in Words)
        {
            hash = hash * 31 + (word == null ? 0 : word.GetHashCode());
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

To answer why a collection does not override `GetHashCode` but uses [`object.GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns a unique value: [Why does C# not implement GetHashCode for Collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907372/why-does-c-sharp-not-implement-gethashcode-for-collections)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this setup works. Why is hash set to 19 and multiplied by 31?

Comment: Because that are primes which reduces the possibility of collisions. Note that a "false" collision is not so bad since it'll be fixed by the `Equals` but many "false" collisions is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're storing `Words` in a `List` then calling `GetHashCode` on it won't give you back a hash of the items in it, instead it'll give you back the hash value from `Object.GetHashCode`.

You need to implement your own hash function that enumerates over the words and generates a hash value.