# What is the fastest way to get a hash of a collection

Tags: c#, performance, hash, hashcode

I am trying to make an extension method in C# that takes in a collection of objects and can make a hash from it. The problem is I haven't been able to figure out a fast way of doing it. I am trying to have it be done in O(1) time but I haven't found any useful information out there. This is what I currently have but it is slow and doesn't really work (its just an example):

```cs
public static int GetCollectionHash(this IEnumerable collection)
{
    HashCode hash = new();
    foreach (var o in collection)
    {
        hash.Add(o);
    }
    return hash.ToHashCode();
}
```

Comment: What are the requirements? When do two subsequent calls to `GetHashCode()` return the same value and when not?

Comment: Have you read this? [Why does C# not implement GetHashCode for Collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907372/why-does-c-sharp-not-implement-gethashcode-for-collections)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way to do what you want is to create your own collection and overriding the add/remove/etc method and update a private variable that contain the hash when they are called

at that point, just read that new variable

Comment: Its not possible, im planning on using this for spans

Comment: @Rubiksmaster02 if you want O(1), you need to trigger something on add/remove and maintain somewhere the hash. everything in that collection would need to be read only too unless you have something that will recalculate the hash on modification

Comment: Sad, is there anything else i can do to speed it up?

Comment: @Rubiksmaster02 i don't know any collection that maintain a global hash of it own collection, you would need custom code, option 1 is what you have. a loop to get the runtime hash of every object in the collection or my solution, a variable to get a calculated one on action but be careful since you would need to maintain that variable if the objects are not read only since the hash could be easily out of sync

Comment: The objects themsevles would be readonly, i wouldnt know how to denote that (maybe a xaml comment), but either way thank you