# Hashset in array of array in c#?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
        HashSet<int> arr = new HashSet<int> { 1, 1, 2 };

        HashSet<List<int>> arrOfarr = new HashSet<List<int>>();
        arrOfarr.Add(new List<int> { 1,2,3 });
        arrOfarr.Add(new List<int> { 1,2,3 });
```

Due to **arr** is a Hashset so obviously it returns {1,2} but I am wondering why **arrOfarr** returns both similar arrays. How does it works? How to change that to not return duplicate arrays?

Comment: You should create a comparer, class which implements `IEqualityComparer<int[]>`

Comment: Also see [Why does C# not implement GetHashCode for Collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907372/why-does-c-sharp-not-implement-gethashcode-for-collections)