# Examining two string arrays for equivalence

Tags: c#

Is there a better way to examine whether two string arrays have the same contents than this?

```
string[] first = new string[]{"cat","and","mouse"};
string[] second = new string[]{"cat","and","mouse"};

bool contentsEqual = true;

if(first.Length == second.Length){
    foreach (string s in first)
    {
        contentsEqual &= second.Contains(s);
    }
}
else{
    contentsEqual = false;
}


Console.WriteLine(contentsEqual.ToString());//    true
```

Comment: Your method doesn't work for comparing the arrays "cat","dog","dog" and "cat","cat","dog".

Comment: Correction, 'yes' you're right thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a built-in method to compare collections in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500/is-there-a-built-in-method-to-compare-collections-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Enumerable.SequenceEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal.aspx) if they're supposed to be in the same order.

Comment: Darn, never even knew about this function hah! Or forget it, at least. One of those little hidden bits in .NET 3.5. I would go and add it to the .NET Hidden Gems thread right now if I had the time!

Comment: If order doesn't matter you could always sort both arrays if you don't mind the extra processing overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using the intersect method. It will give you all the matching values and then you can just compare the count of the resulting array with one the arrays that were compared.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is `O(n^2)`. If the arrays have the same length, sort them, then compare elements in the same position. This is `O(n log n)`.

Or you can use a [hash set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495294.aspx) or [dictionary](http://dotnetperls.com/dictionary-keys): insert each word in the first array, then see if every word in the second array is in the set or dictionary. This is `O(n)` on average.

Comment: The hash set method doesn't deal with duplicates correctly unless you also store a count with each word.

Comment: @Simon - yes, personally I would use a `Dictionary<string, int>`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with the logic of the method, but the fact that you're testing `Contains` for each item in the first sequence means the algorithm runs in `O(n^2)` time in general. You can also make one or two other smaller optimisations and improvements

I would implement such a function as follows. Define an extension method as such (example in .NET 4.0).

```
public static bool SequenceEquals<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq1, IEnumerable<T> seq2)
{
    foreach (var pair in Enumerable.Zip(seq1, seq2)
    {
        if (!pair.Item1.Equals(pair.Item2))
            return;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is assuming that the order of the elements matters, I guess?

Answer (score 1):

You could try Enumerable.Intersect: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx

The result of the operation is every element that is common to both arrays. If the length of the result is equal to the length of both arrays, then the two arrays contain the same items.

Enumerable.Union: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx would work too; just check that the result of the Union operation has length of zero (meaning there are no elements that are unique to only one array);

Although I'm not exactly sure how the functions handle duplicates.