# How to compare two List<String> using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

The two lists are like

```
          LISTONE    "ONE", "TWO", "THREE"
          LISTTWO    "ONE", "TWO", "THREE"
```

i need to compare the whether the items in two lists are in same order or not.

Is there any way to do this in LINQ

Comment: possible duplicate of [Examining two string arrays for equivalence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250887/examining-two-string-arrays-for-equivalence)

Comment: The SequenceEqual operator (extension method) seems like what you'd want, unless ListOne is allowed to have items that are not in ListTwo or vice-versa.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a built-in method to compare collections in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500/is-there-a-built-in-method-to-compare-collections-in-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe:

```
bool equal = collection1.SequenceEqual(collection2);
```

See also: [Comparing two collections for equality irrespective of the order of items in them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098/comparing-two-collections-for-equality)

Comment: The `OrderBy` calls would mean that the order was ignored: but Pramodh wants to see if they are in the same order

Comment: yeah sorry, don't know why I initially put those in there :)

Comment: +1 great tip - thanks - you saved me from writing some terrible, terrible code!

Answer (score 2):

Determine if both lists contain the same data in same order:

```
bool result = list1.SequenceEqual(list2);
```

Same entries in different order:

```
bool result = list1.Intersect(list2).Count() == list1.Count;
```

Comment: Watch out with the second version. The `Intersect` method uses set intersection, so you might get unexpected results if one or both of the lists contain duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

If you know there can't be duplicates:

```
bool result = a.All(item => a.IndexOf(item) == b.IndexOf(item));
```

Otherwise

```
bool result = a.SequenceEquals(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> list1;
List<string> list2;

bool sameOrder = list1.SequenceEqual(list2);
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the correct answers, but as a thought, If you know the lists will have the same data but may be in different order, Why not just sort the lists to guarantee the same order.

```
var newList = LISTONE.OrderBy(x=>x.[sequence]).ToList();
```