# Compare two List<string> using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list

What is the best way to compare two lists based on **values**, **order** and the **number of values**. So all of the lists below should be different.

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "1", "2" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "2", "1" };
var list3 = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" };
```

Comment: Compare usually means to determine order. You just want to determine equality right?

Comment: I guess I do. I want to check the equality of the lists based on those criteria.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare two List<String> using LINQ in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319787/how-to-compare-two-liststring-using-linq-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

See http://ideone.com/yZeYRh

```
var a = new [] { "1", "2", "3" };
var b = new [] { "1", "2" };
var c = new [] { "2", "1" };

Console.WriteLine(a.SequenceEqual(b)); // false
Console.WriteLine(a.SequenceEqual(c)); // false
Console.WriteLine(c.SequenceEqual(b)); // false
```

It comes from the namespace `System.Linq` and can be used on any `IEnumerable`.

You can also pass it an `IEqualityComparer` to for example also do:

```
var d = new [] { "a", "B" };
var e = new [] { "A", "b" };

Console.WriteLine(d.SequenceEqual(e, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Zip for this, but you still need to manually compare Count.

```
lista.Count() ==listb.Count() && lista.Zip(listb, Equals).All(a=>a);
```

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by length?

Comment: I mean Count, I've included it

Comment: Thanks weston, so now it will handle all of the criteria?

Comment: Use sequence equal though. I didn't know about that.