# Other Ways To Code Side By Side Enumeration?

Tags: c#, enumeration

I was wondering if any one could show me any other ways this method could be written, perhaps using LINQ?

```
private static bool CompareManyFoos(ManyFoos expected, ManyFoos actual)
{
    IEnumerator<Foo> expFooAtor = expected.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator<Foo> actFooAtor = actual.GetEnumerator();

    while (expFooAtor.MoveNext())
    {
        if (actFooAtor.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!FoosEqual(expFooAtor.Current, actFooAtor.Current)) return false;
        }
        else
        {
            MissingFoo(expFooAtor.Current);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT**

I've had to patch up my sample code a bit as I made some mistakes, sorry all.  This is the original method, I adapted my sample code from:

```
    private static bool CompareXElementsChildXNodes(XElement expectedXElement, XElement actualXElement,
                                                    ref string message)
    {
        _itemLocator.LevelDown();

        IEnumerator<XNode> expectedNodeRator = expectedXElement.Nodes().GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator<XNode> actualNodeRator = actualXElement.Nodes().GetEnumerator();

        while (expectedNodeRator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (actualNodeRator.MoveNext())
            {
                if (CompareXNodes(expectedNodeRator.Current, actualNodeRator.Current, ref message))
                {
                    _itemLocator.NextNode();
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ExpectedXNodeActuallyMissing(expectedNodeRator.Current, ref message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        _itemLocator.LevelUp();

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I don't even think your code works for what you want to do. What do you want to do actually?

Comment: @manojlds I adapted the example from my application's code which is tested.  Can you see a mistake?  If FoosEqual returns true, continue returns to the start of the loop, until there are no more expected Foos, if FoosEqual returns false or there are less actual Foos than expected the method returns false. (I've cleaned it up slightly in an edit).

Comment: Your sample code would return true if `expFooAtor` has less elements than `actFooAtor` - is that what you want?

Comment: @BrokenGlass ah, thanks, I let that slip the net.  No that's not what I want to happen.  edit - I think I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) would be what you're looking for?

Comment: Good answer.  I should have remembered SequenceEqual from a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250887/examining-two-string-arrays-for-equivalence) I asked a few months ago, shame on me :( .  If you look at the second code sample I've added to my question could I still use SequenceEqual and do what I need to do with _itemLocator?

Comment: There's a second overload of SequenceEquals that allows you to define a separate IEqualityComparer<T>, which is where you would put the code in CompareXNodes(). If I read your code correctly, you could replace it with: `expectedXElement.Nodes().SequenceEquals(actualXElement.Nodes(), compareXNodesComparer();`.