# How should I compare values in two lists?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two lists

```
List 01 => { A, B, C, D, E }
List 02 => { F, F, F, F, E }
```

I need to check if one element of `List 02` exists in `List 01`, so the following should be `false`.

```
List 01 => { A, B, C, D, E }
List 02 => { F, F, F, F, F } // no element matches
```

And here it should be `true`.

```
List 01 => { A, B, C, D, E }
List 02 => { F, F, F, F, B } // last element matches
```

How can I check that?

I'm concerned about **performance** as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500/is-there-a-built-in-method-to-compare-collections-in-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do it:

#### [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If the result of the intersection result in 1 or more elements, it means that at least one equal element.

```
var result = list01.Intersect(list02);
bool hasElement = result.Any();
```

I recommend the use of this method.

It is possible to pass a `IEqualityComparer<T>` as the second parameter in case you need to compare complex types.

#### [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If the result of a except has different amount of elements in total, it means that there is at least one equal element.

```
var result = list01.Except(list02);
bool hasElement = result.Count() != list01.Count;
```

It is possible to pass a `IEqualityComparer<T>` as the second parameter in case you need to compare complex types.

#### [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If any element in the list01 is equal any element in the list02, it means that there is at least one equal element.

```
bool hasElement = list01.Any(e => list02.Any(o => o == e));
```

#### [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) e [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If any element in the list01 is found in list02, it means that there is at lease one equal element.

```
bool hasElement = list01.Any(e => list02.IndexOf(e) != -1);
```

The disadvantage of `IndexOf` is that you can't pass a `IEqualityComparer<T>`, instead it will always use the default, `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`.

---

#### Performance

In a big list, `list01.Any(e => list02.Any(o => o == e))` will have a good performance **only if** one of the values from the beginning of the first in contained in the second list. Otherwise the performance will be awful, as the iterations are sequential.

In a performance test I got the following results:

Lists with 5 elements each, tested 10000000 times.

```
Intersect     : 00:00:02.9260135
Except        : 00:00:03.4404527
AnyAny        : 00:00:06.5709693
AnyIndexOf    : 00:00:01.9882278
```

Lists with 100000 elements each, tested 500 times. The last element of list02 is equal to the third element in list01:

```
Intersect     : 00:00:02.4397784
Except        : 00:00:04.2595364
AnyAny        : 00:00:02.9761128
AnyIndexOf    : 00:00:00.0919344
```

Lists with 100000 elements each, tested 500 times. The last element of list02 is equal to the last element in list01.

```
Intersect     : 00:00:02.4927969
Except        : 00:00:04.2668677
AnyAny        : more than a minute and I dropped the test
AnyIndexOf    : more than a minute and I dropped the test
```

Answer (score 13):

```
list1.Intersect(list2).Any()
```

This will be most performant as it uses HashSets.

Answer (score 5):

`Enumerable.Except` & `Enumerable.Intersect`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment on the other answer. I've tested it with two lists of size `1000`. Using `Intersect` against `Any` and `Contains`, the result was ~1300 ticks vs ~32000 ticks (tested using Stopwatches).

Answer (score 3):

try

```
list1.Any(e => list2.Contains(e));
```

e.g.

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "F", "F", "F" };

list1.Any(e => list2.Contains(e)); // returns false

var list3 = new List<string> { "F", "F", "D" };

list1.Any(e => list3.Contains(e)); // returns true
```

**UPDATE:** as leppie points out, using Intersect will be more performant, esp if the lists are large.

Comment: While the solution is correct, this will run in O(n^2) whereas the other methods (as mentioned by me) will run in O(n).