# Matching a string with XML with value stored over multiple elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to find out if some string has a match in an XML file.

for example:

```
string test="New York, USA";
```

in an XML file formated this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<line>
    <word>New</word>
    <word>York,</word>
    <word>USA</word>
</line>
```

so that every word may or may not be in a different element

What is the most easiest way to do this?
I was thinking about matching each word separately while saving the partial results but it seems to me like there have to be easier way.

Comment: Parse the XML, populate all values in `List<string>`, use ``.Join`` to concatenate elements and compare with `test`.

Comment: How are you going to handle the space?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare word by word you can compare this using two string lists.
using below you can get xml to List

```
List<string> list = doc.Root.Descendants("line").Descendants()
                    .Select(element => element.Value)
                    .ToList();
```

Then take your comparison string to list

```
string words = "New York, USA";
List<string> result = words.Split(' ').ToList();
```

Compare both lists using Intersect(). refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435152/compare-list-and-return-matches-in-c-sharp)

```
 var matcheditems = list.Intersect(result);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: What if the string would span over multiple "line" elements containing its own "word" elements? And what if i wanted to access attributes of the first "word" element that contain part of the string?