# How to pick item from another list if my conditions match?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query regarding C# list.

I have two different types (account  and accountDescriptionHistory) of lists. accountID and accountdescription two column present in both the list.

```
var account = new List<Account>();
var accountDescriptionHistory = new List<AccountDescriptionHistory>();
```

Now, I want to prepare a result list based on below conditions.

1. If accountID match, Pick a accountdescription from accountDescriptionHistory list.
2. Result list should be type of List();

Class definition

```
public class Account
{

    /// <summary>
    /// The account number
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The account's description
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Account Description class :

```
    public class AccountDescriptionHistory : EntityModel<AccountDescriptionHistory>
    {
        #region Public Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// The account description of an account that is valid for a specific date range
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string AccountDescription { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The account this AccountDescriptionHistory is associated with.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare List and return matches in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435152/compare-list-and-return-matches-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Please show the class definitions.

Comment: @Se0ng11 No, I guess, I want to prepare list not want to return the matching item.Also, my question is regarding to return the list not an single item. Matching item should be added in list itself if condition match.

Comment: @AmitSamnani - You ask to match on `accountID`, but your object model doesn't have that property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is unclear on the exact output. Having said that.

**Given**

```
List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>
{ 
    new Account {AccountNumber = "1", Description = "Account 1"}, 
    new Account {AccountNumber = "2", Description = "Account 2"},
    new Account {AccountNumber = "4", Description = "Account 4"}, 
};

List<AccountDescriptionHistory> accountHistories = new List<AccountDescriptionHistory>
{ 
    new AccountDescriptionHistory {AccountDescription = "History Account 1", Account = accounts[0] }, 
    new AccountDescriptionHistory {AccountDescription = "History Account 2", Account = accounts[1] }, 
    new AccountDescriptionHistory {AccountDescription = "History Account 3", Account = new Account {AccountNumber = "3", Description = "Account 3"} }, 
};
```

And we're wanting to find all the `accountHistories` that exist in `accounts` using the `AccountNumber`, we can write a `Where` clause to find all this:

```
List<AccountDescriptionHistory> result = accountHistories
    .Where(x => accounts.Any(y => y.AccountNumber == x.Account.AccountNumber))
    .ToList();
```

If you're wanting to only retrieve the `AccountDescription` from the result, you can write:

```
List<string> result = accountHistories
    .Where(x => accounts.Any(y => y.AccountNumber == x.Account.AccountNumber))
    .Select(x => x.AccountDescription)
    .ToList();
```

If you're wanting to transform the result into an `Account` with the description from `AccountDescriptionHistory`, you can do the following:

```
List<Account> result = accountHistories
    .Where(x => accounts.Any(y => y.AccountNumber == x.Account.AccountNumber))
    .Select(x => new Account {AccountNumber = x.Account.AccountNumber, Description = x.AccountDescription})
    .ToList();
```

**Edit**

You can create a function like this:

```
static Account WithDescriptionHistory(Account account, IEnumerable<AccountDescriptionHistory> accountHistories)
{
    AccountDescriptionHistory accountHistory = accountHistories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Account.AccountNumber == account.AccountNumber);
    account.Description = accountHistory?.AccountDescription ?? account.Description;
    return account;
}
```

Than transform the original `account` variable like:

```
accounts = accounts
    .Select(x => WithDescriptionHistory(x, accountHistories))
    .ToList();
```

**Output**

```
History Account 1
History Account 2
Account 4
```

Comment: You don't need to nest on `accounts` like that. The `AccountDescriptionHistory` instance contains its `Account`. You only have to do this: `accountDescriptionHistory.Where(x => x.Account.AccountNumber == accountNumberToFind).Select(x => x.AccountDescription).ToList()`.

Comment: @Hayden : This is a near by solution.But I am getting new account in account list.i also need old items as well. just want to replace the description from history list to accountlist  if condition match

Answer (score 1):

So base on your comment you need this code

```
foreach (var a in account)
{
    if (!accountDescriptionHistory.Any(x => x.accountID == a.accountID)) continue;
    a.Description = accountDescriptionHistory.FirstOrDefault(x => x.accountID == a.accountID).AccountDescription;
}
```

Comment: What I want is to replace a accountdescription in account list from the description of accountdescriptionhistory list. The result should be manipulate only description column in account list if condition match but result should be in form of var account = new List<Account>();

Comment: I Changed my answer base on your comment

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you had these two classes:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }
}
```

You could use the LINQ Join statement to create a list of the descriptions matched to the Id from the first list

```
    List<A> one = new List<A>
    { 
        new A {Id = 1}, 
        new A {Id = 2} 
    };
    List<B> two = new List<B>
    { 
        new B {Id = 1, desc = "test"}, 
        new B {Id = 2, desc = "test two"} 
    };
    
    var result = one.Join(
        two, 
        x => x.Id, 
        y => y.Id, 
        (x, y) => new {Id = x.Id, Desc = y.desc}
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: what type of result i would get.?? would it be type "A" OR "B"??

Comment: See the line (x, y) => new {Id = x.Id, Desc = y.desc}, that's where you return the type you want, so in this example I am returning a new anonymous type with fields I picked, if you put the line (x,y) => y it would return type "B"

Comment: @Sam - The OP has provided an object model. It would be ideal if your answer used their model. In any case, from what I can see in the question, your object model doesn't apply.

Comment: The object model wasn't in the question when I answered, my answer is based on an incorrect assumption. @AmitSamnani can you respond to Enigmativity's comment on your question and I can update

Comment: @sam can you please say, How can i return type of A but it has property of B description if condition match.

Comment: @AmitSamnani, you will need to do a `Select` on the result back to `Account`. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Amit I hope this helps

```
public partial class TesterForm : Form
{
    List<Account> account = new List<Account>();
    List<AccountDescriptionHistory> accountDescriptionHistory = new List<AccountDescriptionHistory>();
    List<AccountDescriptionHistory> resultlist = new List<AccountDescriptionHistory>();

    public TesterForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class Account
    {
        public int accountID { get; set; }
        public string accountdescription { get; set; }
    }

    public class AccountDescriptionHistory
    {
        public int accountID { get; set; }
        public string accountdescription { get; set; }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Account accountmodel = new Account();
        accountmodel.accountID = 1;
        accountmodel.accountdescription = "desc1";
        account.Add(accountmodel);
        Account accountmodel1 = new Account();
        accountmodel1.accountID = 2;
        accountmodel1.accountdescription = "desc2";
        account.Add(accountmodel1);
        Account accountmodel3 = new Account();
        accountmodel3.accountID = 3;
        accountmodel3.accountdescription = "desc3";
        account.Add(accountmodel3);

        AccountDescriptionHistory accountdescmodel = new AccountDescriptionHistory();
        accountdescmodel.accountID = 3;
        accountdescmodel.accountdescription = "desc4";
        accountDescriptionHistory.Add(accountdescmodel);
        AccountDescriptionHistory accountdescmodel2 = new AccountDescriptionHistory();
        accountdescmodel2.accountID = 4;
        accountdescmodel2.accountdescription = "desc5";
        accountDescriptionHistory.Add(accountdescmodel2);
        AccountDescriptionHistory accountdescmodel3 = new AccountDescriptionHistory();
        accountdescmodel3.accountID = 5;
        accountdescmodel3.accountdescription = "desc6";
        accountDescriptionHistory.Add(accountdescmodel3);


    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Account item in account)
        {
            foreach (AccountDescriptionHistory item2 in accountDescriptionHistory)
            {
                if (item.accountID==item2.accountID)
                {
                    AccountDescriptionHistory history = new AccountDescriptionHistory();
                    history.accountID = item.accountID;
                    history.accountdescription = item2.accountdescription;
                    resultlist.Add(history);
                }
            }
        }
        comboBox1.DataSource = resultlist;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "accountdescription";
    }
}
```

I am using Visual studio 2019 Forms, you will need two buttons and a combobutton to see the result as i tested it.
add to your form combobox1, button1 and button2.

Comment: The solution provided should be independent from the UI platform you're using.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with Windows forms. Also you got the OP's object model wrong.

Comment: @Enigmativity I posted my answer before the question was edited.

Comment: @Mohammed - Perhaps fix the answer then?