# Check if two collections are equal

Tags: c#, collections, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a built-in method to compare collections in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500/is-there-a-built-in-method-to-compare-collections-in-c)
>   [Comparing two collections for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098/comparing-two-collections-for-equality)

I have tow collections that i want to check to see if the values contained within are not eqaul.

```
   SearchResultCollection Users1 = ds1.FindAll();
   SearchResultCollection Users2 = ds2.FindAll();
```

Next i use 2 foreach loops to iterate through and then assign the variables.

```
foreach (SearchResult users in Users1)
{
   string ManagerID = users.Properties["OrgUnitManagerName"][0].ToString();
   string subGroup = users.Properties["EmployeeSubGroup"][0].ToString();
   string cn = users.Properties["cn"][0].ToString();

   foreach (SearchResult user in Users2)
   {
     string uid = absaUser.Properties["uid"][0].ToString();
   }
}
```

What i want to do is: check which users from User1 that do not exixt in user2 and print out that list.

```
if(cn != uid)
  {
  }
```

This doesnt seem to work. 
Any Ideas?

Comment: Related thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500/is-there-a-built-in-method-to-compare-collections-in-c

Answer (score 3):

1. Check they both have the same number of records, bail out if not
2. Do an `list1.Except(list2)` - if there are any results, bail out

Else - success, they match

Note: this uses the LINQ extension method `Except`, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx .  Simply put, `list1.Except(list2)` gives you all items in `list1`, except those in `list2`.

The objects will need to implement `Equals` to compare equality correctly.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
bool AreIdentical = (Users1.Count == Users2.Count ) && (Users1.Except (Users2).Count() == 0) && (Users2.Except (Users1).Count() == 0);
```

EDIT - as per comments:

To just get User in User1 and not in User2 use:

```
var In1ButNotIn2 = Users1.Except (Users2);
```

Comment: "What i want to do is: check which users from User1 that do not exixt in user2 and print out that list."

Comment: Ok so basically what my answer says, but 5 minutes later. OK