# Method to Compare objects

Tags: c#, generics, compare, system.reflection

I am working on a method that can pass in 2 objects of the same type and it will compare the two. In the end I am planning on overloading it to accept property names etc to evaluate only those or exclude only those form the evaluation. That will have to happen after I get the basic full compare working.

I have be been able to compare value types and reference types. Where I am stuck is being able to compare properties that are Enumerable. The `else` statement is what I cannot get to work correctly.

```
public static void CompareObjects<T>(T obj1, T obj2)
{
    foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        var obj1Prop = property.GetValue(obj1);
        var obj2Prop = property.GetValue(obj2);

        //for value types
        if (property.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || property.PropertyType.IsValueType || property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            if (obj1Prop != obj2Prop)
                Console.WriteLine($"Object 1 {property.Name}:{obj1Prop}{Environment.NewLine}Object 2 {property.Name}:{obj2Prop}{Environment.NewLine}");
            }
            //for objects
            else if (property.PropertyType.IsClass && !typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
            {
                dynamic obj1PropObj = Convert.ChangeType(obj1Prop, property.PropertyType);
                dynamic obj2PropObj = Convert.ChangeType(obj2Prop, property.PropertyType);
                CompareObjects(obj1PropObj, obj2PropObj);
            }
            //for Enumerables
            else
            {
                var enumerablePropObj1 = property.GetValue(obj1) as IEnumerable;
                var enumerablePropObj2 = property.GetValue(obj2) as IEnumerable;

                if (enumerablePropObj1 == null) continue;
                if (enumerablePropObj2 == null) continue;

                var list1 = enumerablePropObj1.GetEnumerator();
                var list2 = enumerablePropObj2.GetEnumerator();

                while (list1.MoveNext())
                {
                    list2.MoveNext();
                    CompareObjects(list1.Current, list2.Current);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This iterates through the list but without the values. The setup that I am using to implement this is as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var student1 = new Student
    {
        FirstName = "John",
        LastName = "Smith",
        Age = 18,
        DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse("1989/03/03"),
        Job = new Job
        {
            Company = "CompanyOne",
            Title = "Supervisor"
         },
         PhoneNumbers = new List<PhoneNumber>
         {
            new PhoneNumber
            {
                Number = "8675309",
                Label = "Home"
            },
            new PhoneNumber
            {
                Number = "1234567",
                Label = "Work"
            }
        }
    };
    var student2 = new Student
    {
        FirstName = "Theodore",
        LastName = "Smith",
        Age = 22,
        DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse("1990/03/03"),
        Job = new Job
        {
            Company = "CompanyOne",
            Title = "Manager"
        },
        PhoneNumbers = new List<PhoneNumber>
        {
            new PhoneNumber
            {
                Number = "8675308",
                Label = "Home"
            },
            new PhoneNumber
            {
                Number = "1234567",
                Label = "Work"
            }
        }
    };

    CompareObjects(student1, student2);
    Console.WriteLine("Done");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: [is-there-a-built-in-method-to-compare-collections-in-c#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43500/463206)

Comment: SequenceEqual will not work because what if the the enumerable is a collection of objects that have a collection property. The recursive call needs to be made by passing in each object in the list to that object can then be evaluated by the method in its own iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your method is generic. When you call it on the sub-collections, the type you are using for the comparison is `System.Object`, which of course has no interesting properties to compare.

Change your method declaration and the preamble of the method:

```
public static void CompareObjects(object obj1, object obj2)
{
    if (obj1.GetType() != obj2.GetType())
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (var property in obj1.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        ...
```

Note that with this approach, you also do not need the `dynamic` and `ChangeType()` code.

Finally, you may want to consider changing your inequality comparison so that instead of using the `!=` operator it uses the `Equals()` method:

```
        if (!obj1Prop.Equals(obj2Prop))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Object 1 {property.Name}:{obj1Prop}{Environment.NewLine}Object 2 {property.Name}:{obj2Prop}{Environment.NewLine}");
        }
```

Even when the method was generic, that would be a good idea; while one is *supposed* to implement the equality and inequality operators if one overrides `Equals()`, that doesn't always happen. When the method is non-generic, of course you won't even get operator overloads for the specific types (at least not without a lot of extra work).

*(I guess you could instead of the above use the same `dynamic`/`ChangeType()` approach you use for the non-enumerable properties, using e.g. `list1.Current.GetType()` as the type instead of `property.PropertyType`; that could allow the method to remain generic. But there's so much extra overhead to `dynamic` and ultimately it will all come back down to executing the same code, I just don't see the point in doing it that way.)*

Comment: Good call. I have to admit when I read this on my phone I had my doubts. Then I tried it when I got home and it worked perfectly. I could even keep the dynamic type. I am going to change that if I can when I start building this to do exactly what I want. The `dynamic`  type and I do not get along. Thanks for the help!