# Comparing two dictionaries that are nested

Tags: c#, dictionary, nested, comparison, equality

I have a dictionary of type public 
`Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>>> metricValue { get; set; }`

and I want to be able to compare this to see if it is equal to another object of same type.  I have tried using equals and gethashcode however I have read around and equals() only does reference equality rather than value.  As I have a nested dictionary, I was wondering what the best way to do this is without having to write a huge amount of code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a built-in method to compare collections in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500/is-there-a-built-in-method-to-compare-collections-in-c)

Comment: @RegisPortalez  I have a multi nested dictionary

Comment: 5-demention dictionary, OMG

Comment: sometimes, writing code is inevitable :)