# Loop through two collections to compare for identical collections in C#

Tags: c#, collections, foreach, compare

I have two collections and I want to loop through each element and compare the corresponding elements in each collection for equality, thus determining if the collections are identical.

Is this possible with a foreach loop or must I use a counter and access the elements by index?

Generally speaking is there a preferred method for comparing collections for equality, like overloading an operator?

TIA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a built-in method to compare collections in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500/is-there-a-built-in-method-to-compare-collections-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.SequenceEqual` method which is used for this purpose. Read [More](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.100).aspx).

Examples below if link is down or removed for some reason.

> Determines whether two sequences are equal by comparing the elements
>   by using the default equality comparer for their type.
>
> The SequenceEqual(IEnumerable, IEnumerable)
>   method enumerates the two source sequences in parallel and compares
>   corresponding elements by using the default equality comparer for
>   TSource, Default. The default equality comparer, Default, is used to
>   compare values of the types that implement the IEqualityComparer
>   generic interface. To compare a custom data type, you need to
>   implement this interface and provide your own GetHashCode and Equals
>   methods for the type.

```
class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public static void SequenceEqualEx1()
{
    Pet pet1 = new Pet { Name = "Turbo", Age = 2 };
    Pet pet2 = new Pet { Name = "Peanut", Age = 8 };

    // Create two lists of pets.
    List<Pet> pets1 = new List<Pet> { pet1, pet2 };
    List<Pet> pets2 = new List<Pet> { pet1, pet2 };

    bool equal = pets1.SequenceEqual(pets2);

    Console.WriteLine(
        "The lists {0} equal.",
        equal ? "are" : "are not");
}

/*
    This code produces the following output:

    The lists are equal.
*/
```

> If you want to compare the actual data of the objects in the sequences
>   instead of just comparing their references, you have to implement the
>   IEqualityComparer generic interface in your class. The following
>   code example shows how to implement this interface in a custom data
>   type and provide GetHashCode and Equals methods.

```
public class Product : IEquatable<Product>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Product other)
    {

        //Check whether the compared object is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;

        //Check whether the compared object references the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal.
        return Code.Equals(other.Code) && Name.Equals(other.Name);
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
        int hashProductName = Name == null ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode();

        //Get hash code for the Code field.
        int hashProductCode = Code.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the product.
        return hashProductName ^ hashProductCode;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Product[] storeA = { new Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 },
                            new Product { Name = "orange", Code = 4 } };

Product[] storeB = { new Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 },
                            new Product { Name = "orange", Code = 4 } };

bool equalAB = storeA.SequenceEqual(storeB);

Console.WriteLine("Equal? " + equalAB);

/*
    This code produces the following output:

    Equal? True
*/
```

Comment: Why not `return Code == other.Code && Name == other.Name;`? You know the types for `Code` and `Name` (`int` and `string`) are sealed types that work well with `==`. Your solution with `Name.Eqauls` will explode if `Name` is `null` (a situation you choose to handle in `GetHashCode`).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen As stated, this example is taken directly from MSDN.

Comment: That does not prevent me from criticizing it.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Absolutely. I was just pointing out that this is not my code.