# .Net dynamic list conversion

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, casting

I have to do a comparison of 2 lists. The problem is that I don't know of what type the field inside the list are, they can be int, string, decimal, enums or even other objects.

I will know the type only on runtime. I was thinking of creating a list of object and cast them to object the problem is that let's say I have a `List<int>` and I'm trying to cast it to object it fails.

Another problem is that  I know there is a list only on runtime. so on runtime I need to transform the variable of type object to a list.

How can I cast that object to List and how can I cast it to let's say list of objects?

Update:

I have and object and by reflection I'm getting the the property of it with

```
var oldProperty = property.GetValue(old);
var newProperty = property.GetValue(new);
```

Once I have the properties values and I can see it's a list I will need to compare those 2. Let's say oldProperty is of type List
I've tried to do something like:

```
var myOldList = (List<object>)oldProperty;
```

If the cast fails with

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'
```

Here you have a look of the function i;m trying to create. Please don't mind of null objects(is not in the scope)

```
 public void SetDifference(object first, object second)
    {
        var properties = first.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            var oldValue = property.GetValue(first);
            var newValue = property.GetValue(second);
            if (Convert.GetTypeCode(newValue) != TypeCode.Object)
            {
                if (!oldValue.Equals(newValue))
                {
                    result.AddDifference(new PrimitiveComparison()
                    {
                        BeforeValue = oldValue.ToString(),
                        AfterValue = newValue.ToString(),
                        PropertyName = property.Name
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (property.PropertyType.Name.Contains("List"))
                {
                    // here fails with the error from above
                    var oldList = (List<object>)oldValue; 
                    var newList = (List<object>)newValue;
                    if (oldList.Count != newList.Count)
                    {
                        result.AddDifference(new PrimitiveComparison()
                        {
                            BeforeValue = oldList.Count.ToString(),
                            AfterValue = newList.Count.ToString(),
                            PropertyName = property.Name + "Count"
                        });
                    }
                    // add the list differences
                    result.AddDifference(SetListDifference(oldList, newList);
                }
                else
                {
                    var diffrence = SetDifference(oldValue, newValue);
                    if (!diffrence.areEqual)
                    {
                        result.AddDifference(diffrence);
                    }
                }

            }
        }


}
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you'd provide a [mcve] rather than just a description. Also, focus on a single problem at a time - it sounds like you're trying to ask two different questions here.

Comment: @JonSkeet okay i'm trying to edit it now. Just a sec

Comment: @Liam sound like that but I need more procesing on that. I need a bit more of a comparison that what is done for list on https://www.nuget.org/packages/CompareNETObjects/ and I was instructed to create our own library

Comment: I don't understand that comment?

Comment: @Liam SequenceEqual requires you to know type of list at compile time, but OP doesn't know that (has just two objects or maybe IEnumerables of unknown type).

Comment: @JonSkeet please see my update hope it helps :)

Comment: No, that's still not a [mcve].

Comment: So it sounds like your trying to do some kind of "deep" object comparison using reflection?

Comment: @Liam yes that's exactly what I'm trying but the problem is that I can't do a validation for list

Comment: You can cast both values to `IList` (non-generic) and compare those

Comment: lets forget programming for a while. do you really can compare two lists which are one has collect apples another bananas. Advice:simply "do not compare"  or question really weak... another solution first : could you please implements your list member by IComparable or second: you will need many (!) IEqualityComparer implementation for every types of member of your lists.

Comment: @NuriYILMAZ If you think that this si not about programming it means you did not understood the problem

Comment: if you are trying to compare two list of diffrent type than its not going to work

Comment: @PranayRana the oldList and new ist from the above exemple have the same type by I do not know how how to compare them. I can't go with a swich on each of them. I will try your thing

Comment: @Radu - you can check my udpated answer you need to use Except method to find list equal or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you do conversion of you list than you can check both the list have same element or not by using `except` method of linq, to find both are equal or not

```
double[] numbers1 = { 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5 };
double[] numbers2 = { 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5 };

IEnumerable<double> onlyInFirstSet = numbers1.Except(numbers2);
if(onlyInFirstSet.Count() ==0)
 Console.WriteLine("equal");
```

for primitive type this works fine but for user defined type you need compare implementation.

Check this blog post for comparing list of two different type : [Difference between list of user defined types](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2016/04/diffence-between-list-of-user-defined.html)

---

If you are aware that is going to be IEnumerable type than you can try

```
 List<object> objlst = (value as IEnumerable<object>).Cast<object>
    ().ToList()
```

you can try like this

```
Type t = typeof(obj);

if (t == typeof(List<int>)) {
    var lst= (List<int>)obj;

} else if (t == typeof(List<string>)) {
    var lst = (List<string>)obj;
} else if (t == typeof(List<decimal>)) {
    var lst = (List<decimal>)obj;
} 
else if (t == typeof(List<EnumName>)) {
    var lst = (List<EnumName>)obj;
}
```

Comment: what about decimal, enums, etc. as stated in the question?

Comment: @Liam - you can add more if condtion right ,,, if you want i can write that also...

Comment: Or he can just use [SequenceEqual](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43505/542251) without any casting, if else, etc.,

Comment: @Liam-- but for that also you need two IEnumerable sequence , you can add you answer also if you think that is the way

Comment: *comparison of 2 lists* List are enumerables?

Comment: @Liam - check here Enumerable.SequenceEqual<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>, IEqualityComparer<TSource>) as per systax you need comparer of type also ...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073.aspx..if you dont know type of object how you are going do that

Comment: @Liam - before putting -1 better to check solution and things you are providing ...i am not saying i am correct based on question i provided answer that may be wrong ...

Comment: @PranayRana I have tested what you've said and (value as IEnumerable<object>) works as expected for any object or string but returns null for int, long decimal and primitives so the .Cast<object> will fail with null pointer exception

Comment: @Radu - for primitive type i suggest second option...you can try that ...

Comment: @Radu - I suggest you can try out Evk opt also that might fit in your requirement

Comment: @PranayRana both ot the answers helped me a lot. I will give you the answer because your's helped me a bit more. Both of them are very good ones.

Answer (score 2):

You can just cast your two values to `IList` and compare them, for example like this:

```
static bool AreEqual(IList first, IList second) {
    if (first.Count != second.Count)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < first.Count; i++) {
        if (!object.Equals(first[i], second[i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```