# Unity how to compare contents of two arrays regardless of order?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Looking for the most efficient way. I found this on comparing lists regardless of order:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1307074/how-do-i-compare-two-lists-for-equality-not-caring.html

What about comparing array contents regardless of order?

Comment: Just  change `List<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` and `foreach` instead of `for` in the body of method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a built-in method to compare collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12470106/34092)

Comment: If this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799427/what-guarantees-are-there-on-the-run-time-complexity-big-o-of-linq-methods can be trusted, then arrayA.Except(arrayB) should give you the difference between two arrays at O(n) or near that. So if the difference has a count of zero then they are equal (assuming their lengths are the same).

Comment: `Except` removes duplicates. So `{1,1,1,2,3,3}` will be the 'same' as `{1,1,2,2,2,3}` if you are using `Except`.

Comment: @mjwills You're right. That was a horrible suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Intersect` method. Here is a simple console application

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var nums1 = new int[] { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 9 };
        var nums2 = new int[] { 1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 2 };

        if (nums1.Intersect(nums2).Any()) // check if there is equal items
        {
            var equalItems = nums1.Intersect(nums2); // get list of equal items (2, 6, 9)

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What will you get if you `Intersect` `{1,1,1,2,3,3}` and `{1,1,2,2,2,3}`?

Comment: @mjwills Why don't you test it? It returns `{1, 2, 3}`

Comment: And that is my point. Your code will say they are the same. **They aren't the same**. `Intersect` has the same downsides as `Except`.